# Fluid width with equally spaced DIVs

Tags: html, css, fluid-layout

I have a fluid width container DIV.

Within this I have 4 DIVs all 300px x 250px...

```
<div id="container">
   <div class="box1"> </div>
   <div class="box2"> </div>
   <div class="box3"> </div>
   <div class="box4"> </div>
</div>
```

What I want to happen is box 1 to be floated left, box 4 to be floated right and box 2 and 3 to be spaced evenly between them.  I want the spacing to be fluid as well so as the browser is made smaller the space becomes smaller also.

[image]

Comment: Why not do `display:inline-block;` instead of float?

Comment: because IE6/IE7 only supports `inline-block` on `inline` elements

Comment: Okay, wasn't sure which browsers you were going for.

Comment: I'm not too worried about IE6, it's IE7 that's preventing me from using this option on this occasion... grrrr at IE! :)

Comment: How can you have `4 DIVs all 300px x 250px`, and yet you want fluid width? Do you mean that `.box1` and `.box4` are both `300px` wide, and the middle two `div`s should have fluid and equal width?

Comment: @thirtydot nope, there is other fluid content on the site, these 4 boxes will contain affiliate links which are 300x250, thats why I want them to be evenly spaced

Comment: That makes no sense to me. I don't understand how you want the width and fluidity to work. Maybe a quick picture would help.

Comment: @thirtydot http://img30.imageshack.us/img30/8350/fluid.png - hope this makes sense

Comment: @Lee Price: That makes perfect sense.

Comment: The closest solution I could think of was to wrap each child .box div in another div that are 25% width. Then, center the child .box div to the wrapper. The .box divs will be spaced evenly, but the left and right div won't be right to the edge.

Comment: The problem here is that you can't evenly space with percentages or pixels since they will change with the window width.  Can't use tables (not that I would) for the same reason.  I think JavaScript will be the only way to do this... otherwise, @Paul Sham's solution works but you'll have some space on the outer left & right.

Comment: I made @Paul Sham's idea into a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6waty/2/).

Comment: @Lee If the precise design is not absolutely critical, I would try the idea that I suggested and that Sparky672 created in JSFiddle. If it is, would you want a Javascript option?

Comment: @thirtydot:  I'm very glad I was careful enough to say, _"I **think** JavaScript will be the only way..."_

Answer (score 445, accepted):

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/EDp8R/

- This works in **IE6+ and  all modern browsers!**
- I've halved your requested dimensions just to make it easier to work with.
- `text-align: justify` combined with `.stretch` is what's handling the positioning.
- `display:inline-block; *display:inline; zoom:1` fixes `inline-block` for IE6/7, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838454/inline-block-doesnt-work-in-internet-explorer-7-6/5838575#5838575).
- `font-size: 0; line-height: 0` fixes a minor issue in IE6.

```css
#container {
  border: 2px dashed #444;
  height: 125px;
  text-align: justify;
  -ms-text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
  text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
  /* just for demo */
  min-width: 612px;
}

.box1,
.box2,
.box3,
.box4 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 125px;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  *display: inline;
  zoom: 1
}

.stretch {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0
}

.box1,
.box3 {
  background: #ccc
}

.box2,
.box4 {
  background: #0ff
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="box1"></div>
  <div class="box2"></div>
  <div class="box3"></div>
  <div class="box4"></div>
  <span class="stretch"></span>
</div>
```

The extra `span` (`.stretch`) can be replaced with `:after`.

This **still works** in all the same browsers as the above solution. `:after` doesn't work in IE6/7, but they're using `distribute-all-lines` anyway, so it doesn't matter.

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/EDp8R/3/

There's a minor downside to `:after`: to make the last row work perfectly in Safari, you have to be careful with the whitespace in the HTML.

Specifically, this doesn't work:

```
<div id="container">
    ..
    <div class="box3"></div>
    <div class="box4"></div>
</div>
```

And this does:

```
<div id="container">
    ..
    <div class="box3"></div>
    <div class="box4"></div></div>
```

---

You can use this for any arbitrary number of child `div`s without adding a `boxN` class to each one by changing

```
.box1, .box2, .box3, .box4 { ...
```

to

```
#container > div { ...
```

This selects any div that is the first child of the `#container` div, and no others below it. To generalize the background colors, you can use the [CSS3 nth-order selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child), although it's only supported in IE9+ and other modern browsers:

```
.box1, .box3 { ...
```

becomes:

```
#container > div:nth-child(odd) { ...
```

**See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/EDp8R/3903/)** for a jsfiddle example.

Comment: Isn't that clever.  Never in a million years would I have thought to use `justify` in such a manner.  Well done and +1, but it's still not sitting right with me for some reason... I don't know why, that's my problem, I guess.  (This is certainly a great example of when there's actually a reason to use a `<span>` in place of a `<div>`.)

Comment: You just edited the question and my comment about `<span>` is obsolete.  It's even better, IMHO.  But just wondering if you could elaborate more about the reasoning for your edits.

Comment: I edited my answer because since I wrote it, I've seen this `distribute-all-lines` thing (can't remember where), which does the same thing, but for only IE6/7. `distribute-all-lines` does work with `div`s, whereas the old solution required a naturally inline element for IE6/7 such as `span`. This new version is indeed better.

Comment: Regarding your notes on whitespace in Safari, I'm seeing no difference at all... the boxes wrap/unwrap to the next line regardless of whitespace.  Mac version 5.06.  Why not just [two containers to get two rows](http://jsfiddle.net/EDp8R/2/)?

Comment: @Sparky672: The Safari/whitespace thing happens for me on Windows 7 with Safari 5.1. Yeah, two containers for two rows works fine here. I've edited my answer (..again) to remove the multiple rows thing and to use the same kind of squares. I was trying to keep this answer in sync with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7041927/how-to-set-auto-margin-boxes-in-flexible-width-design-using-css/7042563#7042563), evidently I got a little confused along the way. Thanks.

Comment: I took me 3h to find that you should have spaces between each boxes in the html. "Justify" extends spaces between the elements and if your content is `<div/><div/><div/>` it does not work. You need to have `<div/> <div/> <div/>`.

Comment: @venimus: This can definitely be fiddly to get right. I'm sure you don't need me to tell you that :)

Comment: just wanted to note that :) because it is hard to note if you work with a generated content (which is the common case). I was thinking to use `justify` for such case, but thank you to provide a working solution. saved me lots of experiments (despite the 3h debugging :D). In addition I could add a note that if you want your last row to be left aligned you should add some extra invisible boxes (to complete the row)

Comment: @venimus: I've wrote another answer using this technique: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10548417/how-to-distribute-floated-elements-evenly-with-a-dynamic-column-and-row-count-in/10550660#10550660. What did you do to get rid of the extra height caused by adding invisible boxes?

Comment: Could You maybe take a look at my question :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10701122/table-like-layout-with-divs-and-overflow

Comment: I was halfway there in that I knew justify could accomplish what I wanted (evenly spaced divs in a fluid row), but for the life of me couldn't figure out the proper implementation. This is an excellent showcase of the span tag! Very clever indeed.

Comment: Soon, all modern browsers will handle this natively with flexbox. Currently it's only [Chrome and Opera](http://caniuse.com/flexbox), but get ready.

Comment: Can someone explain *why* the .stretch is necessary?

Comment: Is the white space always needed after each Div? I noticed it won't work with a container width set to 611px, it causes the last Div to break into the next row. I was thinking it would flush the borders if set to 600px, but no

Comment: @ash It's something to do with pushing the extremities of the container. Not sure actually. Can anyone give in-depth explanation ?

Comment: Is it just me, or does the stretch add a few px to the parent containers size? How best to remove, and would it always be fixed amount?

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11589590/text-align-justify-inline-block-elements-properly

Comment: This is the best cross-browser solution I've seen for this sort of layout. Thank you. I'm with ash though in that I still don't completely understand why the stretch span causes the layout to render the way it does. As far as I can tell, it essentially forces a new line, which causes the four divs before it to occupy one entire line. Another thing I'm still curious about as well is if it's possible to make the last line unjustified when the above is used on divs spanning multiple lines with an uneven amount of divs in the final row. Maybe it's impossible without JS/back-end, but just curious.

Comment: @HartleySan: The `.stretch`/`:after` is needed because (typically) with justified text, [the last line is *not* justified](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Justification_(typesetting)). Here, we do want the last line to be justified, hence the need for `:after`. As for your second question, I explored that a while ago [in a previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10548417/10550660#10550660). In that answer, JavaScript was required. If you need to support older browsers (IE8) then I believe you do need JavaScript.

Comment: @thirtydot, thank you very much for that quick answer. After reading your answer and playing with the fiddle a bit more, it's starting to make sense. Also, I now understand why people wanted to add invisible divs at the end. Doing so seems to make the last row line up with the other rows, even if there isn't a full row of divs in the last row. Naturally, as you commented, JS or some server-side scripting is definitely required to pull that off though. Thanks again, and awesome answer.

Comment: Noticed, that on FF 25 whitespace between divs matters. Without it their distribution breaks.

Comment: I edited the fiddle to work without needing to specify a class on each child `div`, and therefore working for _any_ arbitrary number of `div`s that fit. http://jsfiddle.net/EDp8R/3903/

Comment: I've found that this technique also works for divs that aren't uniform in size, which is very handy for navs and such - just remove the width rule on the boxes.

Comment: @iceydee As far as I can see the stretch is adding quite a few pixels to the bottom of the parent container. Adding `line-height:0` to the parent container reduces the space quite a bit but does not reduce it to zero

Comment: @iceydee Adding line-height:0; to the parent container and vertical-align:top; to the container's pseudo element should remove the extra space completely.

Comment: Has anyone found a way to make this work with Jade? I'm not sure how to get the space to set off the justification.

Comment: Here's how to get the space for an angular `ng-repeat` item written in 
Jade: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39026722/4760334
HTML: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19507046/4760334

Answer (score 158):

The easiest way to do this now is with a flexbox:

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

The CSS is then simply:

```
#container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QPrk3/

**However**, this is currently only supported by relatively recent browsers (http://caniuse.com/flexbox).
Also, the spec for flexbox layout has changed a few times, so it's possible to cover more browsers by additionally including an older syntax:

http://css-tricks.com/old-flexbox-and-new-flexbox/

http://css-tricks.com/using-flexbox/

Comment: Thank you for this, so easy, I applied it to four even spaced lists in  a footer fixed at the bottom of a page.  Worked a treat in FF28.0, Chrome 34.0.1847.116 m and IE11.

Comment: Flexbox is not the most supported tool across the web and it does not beat classic approach of margin and padding.

Comment: For everyone looking for justifying multiple divs with not defined widht: use flex-wrap with display: flex option. It will wrap divs with dynamic width.

Answer (score 20):

If **css3** is an option, this can be done using the css `calc()` function.

### Case 1: Justifying boxes on a single line ( [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/3ngvz/3/) )

Markup is simple - a bunch of divs with some container element.

CSS looks like this:

```
div
{
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
    background:pink;
    width: 50px;
    margin-right: calc((100% - 300px) / 5 - 1px); 
}
div:last-child
{
    margin-right:0;
}
```

where *-1px* to fix an IE9+ calc/rounding bug - see [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16658482/703717)

### Case 2: Justifying boxes on  multiple lines ( [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/Vfffg/16/) )

Here, in addition to the `calc()` function, `media queries` are necessary.

The basic idea is to set up a media query for each #columns states, where I then use calc() to work out the margin-right on each of the elements (except the ones in the last column).

This sounds like a lot of work, but if you're using LESS or SASS this can be done quite easily

(It can still be done with regular css, but then you'll have to do all the calculations manually, and then if you change your box width - you have to work out everything again)

Below is an example using LESS: (You can copy/paste this code [**here**](http://less2css.org/) to play with it, [it's also the code I used to generate the above mentioned fiddle])

```
@min-margin: 15px;
@div-width: 150px;

@3divs: (@div-width * 3);
@4divs: (@div-width * 4);
@5divs: (@div-width * 5);
@6divs: (@div-width * 6);
@7divs: (@div-width * 7);

@3divs-width: (@3divs + @min-margin * 2);
@4divs-width: (@4divs + @min-margin * 3);
@5divs-width: (@5divs + @min-margin * 4);
@6divs-width: (@6divs + @min-margin * 5);
@7divs-width: (@7divs + @min-margin * 6);


*{margin:0;padding:0;}

.container
{
    overflow: auto;
    display: block;
    min-width: @3divs-width;
}
.container > div
{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    width: @div-width;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
    float:left;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}

@media (max-width: @3divs-width) {
    .container > div {  
        margin-right: @min-margin;
    }
    .container > div:nth-child(3n) {  
        margin-right: 0;
    }
}

@media (min-width: @3divs-width) and (max-width: @4divs-width) {
    .container > div {  
        margin-right: ~"calc((100% - @{3divs})/2 - 1px)";
    }
    .container > div:nth-child(3n) {  
        margin-right: 0;
    }
}

@media (min-width: @4divs-width) and (max-width: @5divs-width) {
    .container > div {  
        margin-right: ~"calc((100% - @{4divs})/3 - 1px)";
    }
    .container > div:nth-child(4n) {  
        margin-right: 0;
    }
}

@media (min-width: @5divs-width) and (max-width: @6divs-width) {
    .container > div {  
        margin-right: ~"calc((100% - @{5divs})/4 - 1px)";
    }
    .container > div:nth-child(5n) {  
        margin-right: 0;
    }
}

@media (min-width: @6divs-width){
    .container > div {  
        margin-right: ~"calc((100% - @{6divs})/5 - 1px)";
    }
    .container > div:nth-child(6n) {  
        margin-right: 0;
    }
}
```

So basically you first need to decide a box-width and a minimum margin that you want between the boxes.

With that, you can work out how much space you need for each state.

Then, use calc() to calcuate the right margin, and nth-child to remove the right margin from the boxes in the final column.

The **advantage** of this answer over the accepted answer which uses `text-align:justify` is that when you have more than one row of boxes - the boxes on the final row don't get 'justified' eg: If there are 2 boxes remaining on the final row - I don't want the first box to be on the left and the next one to be on the right - but rather that the boxes follow each other in order.

Regarding **browser support**: This will work on IE9+,Firefox,Chrome,Safari6.0+ - (see [**here**](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc) for more details) <strike>However i noticed that on IE9+ there's a bit of a glitch between media query states. [if someone knows how to fix this i'd really like to know :) ]</strike>    <-- FIXED [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16658482/703717)

Answer (score 20):

Other posts have mentioned [flexbox](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/), but if **more than one row of items is necessary**, flexbox's `space-between` property **fails** (see the end of the post)

To date, the only clean solution for this is with the

### [CSS Grid Layout Module](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/) ([Codepen demo](http://codepen.io/danield770/pen/gmzEMZ?editors=1100))

Basically the relevant code necessary boils down to this:

```
ul {
  display: grid; /* (1) */
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 120px); /* (2) */
  grid-gap: 1rem; /* (3) */
  justify-content: space-between; /* (4) */
  align-content: flex-start; /* (5) */
}
```

1) Make the container element a grid container

2) Set the grid with an 'auto' amount of columns - as necessary. This is done for responsive layouts. The width of each column will be 120px. (Note the use of `auto-fit` (as apposed to `auto-fill`) which (for a 1-row layout) collapses empty tracks to 0 - allowing the items to expand to take up the remaining space. (check out **[this demo](https://codepen.io/danield770/pen/GOQZoQ?editors=1100)** to see what I'm talking about) ).

3) Set gaps/gutters for the grid rows and columns - here, since want a 'space-between' layout - the gap will actually be a **minimum gap** because it will grow as necessary.

4) and 5) - Similar to flexbox.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 120px);
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-content: flex-start;
  
  /* boring properties: */
  list-style: none;
  width: 90vw;
  height: 90vh;
  margin: 2vh auto;
  border: 5px solid green;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}
li {
  background: tomato;
  height: 120px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

### [Codepen demo](http://codepen.io/danield770/pen/gmzEMZ?editors=1100) (Resize to see the effect)

---

### Browser Support - [Caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid)

Currently supported by Chrome (Blink), Firefox, Safari and Edge! ... with partial support from IE (See [this post](https://rachelandrew.co.uk/archives/2016/11/26/should-i-try-to-use-the-ie-implementation-of-css-grid-layout/) by Rachel Andrew)

---

### NB:

Flexbox's `space-between` property works great for one row of items, but when applied to a flex container which wraps it's items - (with `flex-wrap: wrap`) - fails, because you have no control over the alignment of the last row of items;
the last row will *always* be justified (usually not what you want)

To demonstrate:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
ul {
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
  
  list-style: none;
  width: 90vw;
  height: 90vh;
  margin: 2vh auto;
  border: 5px solid green;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  
}
li {
  background: tomato;
  width: 110px;
  height: 80px;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

[**Codepen**](http://codepen.io/danield770/pen/jBxJEN) (Resize to see what i'm talking about)

---

Further reading on CSS grids:

- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout)
- [Jen Simmons - Learn CSS grid](http://jensimmons.com/post/feb-27-2017/learn-css-grid)
- [A Complete Guide to CSS Grid | Codrops CSS Reference](https://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/grid/)
- [A Complete Guide to Grid - CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

Comment: Very underrated answer. This was the simplest and most effective way to achieve what I wanted to do. Thank you.

Comment: This was the smallest amount of CSS (and no JS!) that produced exactly the behaviour I was looking for, with some tweaking for size and space.

Comment: I've been looking for this for a while and finally found it!. Thanks @Danield

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me with 5 images in diferent sizes.

1. Create a container div
2. An Unordered list for the images
3. On css the unordened must be displayed vertically and without bullets
4. Justify content of container div

This works because of justify-content:space-between, and it's on a list, displayed horizontally.

On CSS

```
 #container {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
 }
    #container ul li{ display:inline; list-style-type:none;
}
```

On html

```
<div id="container"> 
  <ul>  
        <li><img src="box1.png"><li>
        <li><img src="box2.png"><li>
        <li><img src="box3.png"><li>
        <li><img src="box4.png"><li>
        <li><img src="box5.png"><li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: While this code may well work, a good answer would include an explanation of how it works and why it is a good solution.

Comment: It's worth noting that flexbox is not (or only partially) supported by IE http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: is this responsive?

Answer (score 1):

in `jQuery` you might target the Parent directly.

> THIS IS USEFUL IF YOU DO NOT KNOW EXACTLY HOW MANY CHILDREN WILL BE
>   ADDED DYNAMICALLY or IF YOU JUST CAN'T FIGURE OUT THEIR NUMBER.

```
var tWidth=0;

$('.children').each(function(i,e){
tWidth += $(e).width();

///Example: If the Children have a padding-left of 10px;..
//You could do instead:
tWidth += ($(e).width()+10);

})
$('#parent').css('width',tWidth);
```

**This will let the `parent` grow horizontally as the `children` are beng added.**

NOTE: This assumes that the `'.children'` have a `width` and `Height` Set

Hope that Helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the number of elements per "row" and the width of the container you can use a selector to add a margin to the elements you need to cause a justified look.

I had rows of three divs I wanted justified so used the:

`.tile:nth-child(3n+2) { margin: 0 10px }`

this allows the center div in each row to have a margin that forces the 1st and 3rd div to the outside edges of the container

Also great for other things like borders background colors etc