# jQuery append breaks flexible width css layout

Tags: jquery, css

I'm using the answers from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7041927/how-to-set-auto-margin-boxes-in-flexible-width-design-using-css). When I create a static page, it works great, but when I use jquery append to create each box, it doesn't work. Each item ends up directly next to each other.

The [jsFiddle that works](http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/79mFr/2/) and the [modified jsfiddle that doesn't work](http://jsfiddle.net/VcsX8/). What would cause this to not work? How can I fix it or work around it?

Comment: The answer I gave in that question can unfortunately be very picky about whitespace. Make sure that you test in Safari, it sometimes gets this wrong in a unique way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$(function() {
    for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
        $('#container').append('<div></div>\n');
    }
})
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VcsX8/1/)**