# How can I center the elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you easily horizontally center a <div> using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618097/how-do-you-easily-horizontally-center-a-div-using-css)

http://jsfiddle.net/rehan008/s5eEf/
Please refer this.

I want to make all the shortcuts center aligned but the last row should be aligned to the left.
Please share if any ideas.

Comment: You should post your code here.

Comment: What do you mean by "Center aligned"? The DIV withing the container? or the text within the shortcut?

Comment: I think the closest thing is adding `text-align:justify` to `.shortcutContainer {}`. This will even the the full rows and move the last row items to the left.

Comment: Any reason you have to use a single cell `table` to wrap contents?

Comment: I can't tell exactly what you want, but this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10548417/how-to-distribute-floated-elements-evenly-with-a-dynamic-column-and-row-count-in/10550660#10550660.

Answer (score 1):

Set all `div` children of `.shortcut` to have a centered margin excluding the last one.

```
.shortcut > div {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.shortcut:last-child > div {
    margin: 0;
}
```

[Update fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s5eEf/21/)

Answer (score 0):

Add this style in your CSS and check. I hope it will work for you

> td {
>       text-align:center; }

Answer (score 0):

To make each div centre aligned (and on a row by itself), which is how I'm interpreting your requirements, you can change the **.shortcut** css style to this:

```
.shortcut{
    border: 1px solid red;
    height:65px;
    width:45px;
    display:block;
    margin:5px auto;
}
```

To make the last shortcut left aligned, simply give it another style:

```
   .lastShortcut{
        border: 1px solid red;
        height:65px;
        width:45px;
        display:block;
        margin:5px 0px;
    }
```

Comment: if you see there is no seperate row for last row of shortcuts

Comment: So put in another div to wrap the elements that you want as your last row. Or add an ID or a second classname to the last div.  Or use the selector that Terric suggested [.shortcut:last-child > div].  Any of those solutions will allow you to specify a different style for the last shortcut.

Comment: you are not understanding what i mean to say.

Comment: all elements are in same div and floating to the left
according to space available the elements will arrange them