# equal margin between divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Suppose you have n **floating** divs in a container. How do you make space between them (margin) to be equal, automatically? it should support window resize event.

I can use JQuery if needed, but I'd rather it to be pure html/css.
Thanks

Comment: I suppose you mean that those divs should *adapt* their margins in order to fill the container?

Comment: Since it's mandatory to be floated, thn `display:table` is out of question. Anyways, in JS, it's quite possible as long as you know at least how many divs per line you want. So you would grab innerWidth() of the container and of each div, divide by the number of div's per line you set up and then calculate the margin of each one. Can try make a code for you when I get home if noone else answers. Anyways, try reading [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10550660/684932), it might help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy! justify them! (using only **CSS**)

*Note*: Don't float them, floating is the LAST thing you should do in many cases.

Here's an example:
[DEMO PAGE](http://codepen.io/vsync/pen/tFwxu)

## HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>another item</li>
    <li>and another</li>
</ul>
```

## CSS

```
ul{ width:100%; text-align:justify; }
ul::after{ content:''; display:inline-block; width:100%; }
  ul li{ display:inline-block; }
```

Comment: I don't get why so many designers keep using floating elements. They're more a bother than anything else.

Comment: that's great, and maybe I should give up on floating

Answer (score 0):

`div {
  float: left;
    margin-left: 5%;
}`