# Justify divs with CSS to fill width of parent container

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a page with a container width 100% so its the entire width of the screen, i have several DIVs in a grid structure, they all have float: left on them and no set width, just a margin of 10px.

Is there a method, using CSS or jQuery, to have the divs fill the entire width and justify themselves to fit the gaps, so the margin changes depending the screen size.

Comment: You say that the divs currently have no set width, but do have a set margin.  Is your intention to make the divs have a fixed width, and have the space between them fluid?

Comment: Yes this is exactly what i'd like

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Check out thirtydot's answer in this thread for a pure CSS/HTML solution without JavaScript that works in all browsers **including IE 6**.

[Fluid width with equally spaced DIVs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865194/fluid-width-with-equally-spaced-divs)

http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/EDp8R/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="box1"></div>
    <div class="box2"></div>
    <div class="box3"></div>
    <div class="box4"></div>
    <span class="stretch"></span>
</div>​
```

**CSS:**

```
#container {
    border: 2px dashed #444;
    height: 125px;

    text-align: justify;
    -ms-text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
    text-justify: distribute-all-lines;

    /* just for demo */
    min-width: 612px;
}

.box1, .box2, .box3, .box4 {
    width: 150px;
    height: 125px;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1
}
.stretch {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0
}

.box1, .box3 {
    background: #ccc
}
.box2, .box4 {
    background: #0ff
}
```

​

Comment: I found a weird bug for this code which appears when you manipulating the DOM. Try adding additonal boxes after initial render appears. Additional box positions are not properly aligned, tested on Chrome

Answer (score 9):

Using CSS3 this is now super easy.

**UPDATE**

Added MS IE support (believe in it or not...). I'm not pretty sure about the FF stuff because Mozilla changed something. I have not so much time. So if someone could maybe correct me...

**UPDATE II**

Moved code to snippet

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  display: -moz-box;
  -moz-box-pack: justify;
  -moz-box-align: center;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  display: box;
  box-pack: justify;
  box-align: center;
}
.child {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">
    Some Content
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    Some Content
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    Some Content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: consider instead: using `space-between` (http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) which is a bit more stable (relative to the stability of flexbox as a whole)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with CSS if specify all dimensions in percents (ie. width, margin, padding).

Or if you want a specific margin or padding, you can use jQuery

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  var $columns = $('.column'),
      numberOfColumns = $columns.length,               
      marginAndPadding = 0,
      newColumnWidth = ($('#container').width() / numberOfColumns) - marginAndPadding,
      newColumnWidthString = newColumnWidth.toString() + "px";

  $columns.css('width', newColumnWidthString);
}).resize();
```