# After adding elements by JavaScript CSS hack don't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I use a hack to [justify `div`s in the container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7051768/justify-divs-with-css-to-fill-width-of-parent-container) (marked answer). It works perfectly in static HTML.

```
<div id="gallery-thumbnails">
    <div class="gallery-thumbnail">
        <img src="1.jpg" alt="alt" title="title">
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-thumbnail">
        <img src="2.jpg" alt="alt" title="title">
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-thumbnail">
        <img src="3.jpg" alt="alt" title="title">
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-thumbnail">
        <img src="4.jpg" alt="alt" title="title">
    </div>
    <span class="stretch"></span>
</div>
```

But when I do this via JS, the hack itself don't work (color styles are applied, I see pictures). Hovewer, the diff tool says that static and generated versions of DOM are identical.

Here's the code

```
var thumbnailsContainer = $('#gallery-thumbnails');
$(thumbnailsContainer).children('*').each(function() {
    $(this).remove();
});

$(lists[index]).children('img').each(function(index, picture) {
    var thumbnail = $('<div>', { class: "gallery-thumbnail" });
    var thumbnailImage = $('<img>', { src: $(picture).attr('src'), alt: $(picture).attr('alt'), title: $(picture).attr('title') });
    $(thumbnail).append(thumbnailImage);
    $(thumbnailsContainer).append(thumbnail);
});

$(thumbnailsContainer).append($('<span>', { class: 'stretch'} ));
```

## Update

[JSFiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/Q4E9d/). If you comment the JS code and re-run, you'll see what I intent to do. If you uncomment, you'll see me failin'.

Comment: What doesnt work? You never really said.

Comment: @cgatian The hack. Divs are not justified when I make DOM via JS.

Comment: Provide a jsfiddle, please.

Comment: @Oriol Done, plz look at the post update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you need spaces between elements, so just add

```
$thumbnailsContainer.append(' ');
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Q4E9d/3/)

Comment: Unbelieveable! You're my savior. But can you explain this? It looks like a sort of magic for me.

Comment: You need spaces because if there's anything between your elements, anything can separate them, and you want them to be separated.