# Text-align: justify not working on dynamically created content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying use text-align:justify and display:inline-block as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7051768/justify-divs-with-css-to-fill-width-of-parent-container) to style some dynamically created elements. After banging my head against the wall checking for CSS conflicts, I finally realized that it was that the alignment wasn't being re-evaluated after the content was created. I'm wondering if anybody knows a work-around for this. Is there a way to force styles to be re-evaluated on a dynamically created element?

EDIT -
HTML:

```
<div id="container" class="flush">

</div>

<div class="flush">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.flush{
text-align: justify;
width: 500px;
height: 250px;
background: #00f;
}

.flush div{
display: inline-block;
width: 101px;
height: 100px;
background: #f00;
}
```

JS:

```
for(var i = 0; i<5; i++){  
  $('#container').append("<div></div>");
}
```

Here's a [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/US8Az/2/) to illustrate. Notice how the hard-coded elements are justified, while the dynamically created ones aren't.

Comment: how do you put the content in the div? since there is not need to do that in css, but in some cases `$(".some").css('width', 300);` will do http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: The content is being created by javascript. Most CSS properties declared in the stylesheet (height, width) are being applied. I think the issue is that the styles on the parent container need to be re-evaluated when the child elements are created.

Comment: Can you post some code and jsfiddle.net example to recreate the issue?

Comment: good suggestion! edited above.

Comment: edited my answer second solution is better

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just add a `space` after dynamically created `div` ;)

```
$('#container').append("<div></div> ");
```

Have phun!

**Edit**

This is better

```
$('#container').append("<div></div>\n\r");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ergec/4pswV/

Comment: Ah, makes total sense. Thanks!