# items loses its alignment after sorting

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

why items loses its alignment after sorting?

I tried writing `css` code again - without success.

Any help?

```js
function sort_tags(){
 let a = $('#selSort').val();
 if(a == 'asc'){
  $('.tag').sort(function(a, b) {
   if (a.textContent < b.textContent) {return -1;}
   else{return 1;}
  }).appendTo('#parent');
 }
 else if(a == 'desc'){
  $('.tag').sort(function(a, b) {
   if (a.textContent < b.textContent) {return 1;}
   else{return -1;}
  }).appendTo('#parent');
 }
 $('.tag').css('display', 'inline-block');
 $('#parent').css('text-align-last', 'justify');
}
```

```css
.parent{
text-align:justify;
text-align-last:justify;
}

.tag{
display:inline-block;
padding:2px 9px;
background:gold;
margin:9px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='parent' id='parent'>
<div class='tag'>aaa</div>
<div class='tag'>bbb</div>
<div class='tag'>ccc</div>
<div class='tag'>ddd</div>
</div>

<select class='selTop' id='selSort' onchange='sort_tags()'>
<option value='asc'>SORT ABC</option>
<option value='desc'>SORT CBA</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flex

```
.parent{
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```js
function sort_tags(){
 let a = $('#selSort').val();
 if(a == 'asc'){
  $('.tag').sort(function(a, b) {
   if (a.textContent < b.textContent) {return -1;}
   else{return 1;}
  }).appendTo('#parent');
 }
 else if(a == 'desc'){
  $('.tag').sort(function(a, b) {
   if (a.textContent < b.textContent) {return 1;}
   else{return -1;}
  }).appendTo('#parent');
 }
}
```

```css
.parent{
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.tag{
display:inline-block;
padding:2px 9px;
background:gold;
margin:9px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='parent' id='parent'>
<div class='tag'>aaa</div>
<div class='tag'>bbb</div>
<div class='tag'>ccc</div>
<div class='tag'>ddd</div>
</div>

<select class='selTop' id='selSort' onchange='sort_tags()'>
<option value='asc'>SORT ABC</option>
<option value='desc'>SORT CBA</option>
</select>
```

Comment: "why items loses its alignment after sorting"?

Comment: Check out this answer [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21412641/text-align-justify-not-working-on-dynamically-created-content/21414068](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21412641/text-align-justify-not-working-on-dynamically-created-content/21414068)

Comment: Solved! Justified items must have a space between them. Thanks a lot.