# Align text vertically in Div

Tags: css

I have some html in the following structure:

```
<div class="input-control">
    <div class="label-wrapper"></div>
    <div class="input-wrapper"></div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.input-control
{
    height:40px;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%
}

.label-wrapper,
.input-wrapper
{
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right:-3px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

.label-wrapper
{
    width:160px;
}
```

All is good - as you the text in the label-wrapper class is vertically centered.

However, what I want to do is make it so that label-wrapper and input-wrapper are floated, left and right respectively.

When I apply a float, I then lose the vertical alignment of the text.

I've tried loads of permutations - anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: Will [this suit](http://jsfiddle.net/22buQ/)?

Comment: Or you can use this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7052088/2329464

Comment: @drip - I'm specifically looking for the vertical alignment

Comment: @Vucko - its a great effort and does work, but absolute positioning may prove restrictive.

Comment: @dotnetnoob how about using `line-height` - [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/22buQ/5/)?

Comment: @Vucko - label wrap is not catered for with line height

Comment: @dotnetnoob so add `text-align:center` - [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/22buQ/6/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Good**

The more clean solution would be this: http://jsfiddle.net/es4Ca/ i think.

```
.input-control
{
    padding: 20px 0px;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%
}

.label-wrapper,
.input-wrapper
{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

.label-wrapper
{
    width:160px;
}

.input-wrapper
{
    width: calc(100% - 164px);
    text-align: right;
}
```

**Complicated and not so clean**

Here is one overly complicated solution: http://jsfiddle.net/jHd3J/3/

```
.input-control
{
    overflow:hidden;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    /*change this...*/
    height: 300px;
}

.inner-input
{
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%;
}


.input-wrapper
{
  margin-left: 160px;
  width: calc(100% - 160px);
  text-align: right;
}

.label-wrapper
{
    width:160px;
    float: left;
}
```

With this HTML:

```
<div class="input-control">
    <div class="inner-input">
        <div class="label-wrapper">
            <label>Hahah</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-wrapper">
            <input type="text" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```