# 2 Divs, variable size and fixed margin inbetween

Tags: html, css

I would like to have two divs sit next to each other. Both divs have their width set to a certain percentage. Between the two divs I want a fixed width margin of 20px. The width of div1 and div2 and the 20px margin should add up to 100% of the available space. (See screenshot below)

Heres a basic jsfiddle to get started: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u7VzB/)

```
code for jsfiddle link to work
```

Is this possible without javascript?

[image: what i want]

Comment: This kind of layout has always been tricky to me. Generally I would have "column" divs which span the entire width (30% and 70% respectively, floated left) but with a padding-right of 20px. Then the last column could have a padding-right of 0px. Also, have you considered CSS frameworks like Twitter Bootstrap, Zurb Foundation, or Yahoo!Pure? I hated the idea of a framework but once I used one, I'll NEVER go back. :)

Comment: @moberemk Does the trick perfectly, but check [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7190768/css-fluid-columns-fixed-margins-the-holy-grail-of-holy-grails) too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest, safest way I know to do something like this is a nested `<div>`, using the outside div as a container for layout purposes. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/u7VzB/1/

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="div1">div#1</div>
    <div id="div2">
        <div>div#2 inner</div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container
{
    color: white;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
#div1
{
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    background-color: black;
}
#div2
{
    float: left;
    width: 70%;
}
#div2 > div {
    margin-left: 20px;   
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Very clever - I can't think of a better way to do it.  I'm not sure it is possible using just .div1 and .div2

Comment: @JohnStrickler It isn't, really; until we get the ability to use math in CSS size definitions, that sort of calculation is impossible to do consistently. It's one of the limits of CSS.

Comment: @moberemk It is possible using just css check my answer below.

Comment: @Mr_Green Clever; didn't know that works like that. Good answer!

Answer (score 2):

You can also do something like this without disturbing HTML code:

```
#container {
    color: white;
    margin-top: 50px;
    position: relative;
}
#div1 {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    background-color: black;
}
#div2 {
    float: left;
    position:absolute;
    left: 30%;
    margin-left: 20px;
    right: 0px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u7VzB/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

try by setting float left, right and reduce the width

```
#container
{
    color: white;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
#div1
{
    float: left;
    width: 29%;
    background-color: black;
}
#div2
{
    float: right;
    width: 69%;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: that would leave 2% inbetween. I want the margin inbetween to always be exactl 20px - not 2%

Comment: Like Marius said, this wouldn't work in all cases; 2% of, say a 1300px div wouldn't work. See my solution for an example of a scalable answer.