# How to create 3-column layout (fixed, fixed, fluid)

Tags: css, html, css-float, liquid-layout

I am trying to create a 3-column layout that works on most mobile browsers. Flex does not work unfortunately.

There is a great help for liquid, fixed, fixed layout (http://www.pagecolumn.com/liquidfixed/3_col_liquid-fix-fix.htm), but I do need fixed, fixed, liquid.

Could not get this done so far and hope for any help on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to have the last element fluid then you can use `float:none;`.

The last element gets the `float:none;` and also a `padding-left` equal to the width of the other two fixed divs.

**HTML**

```
<div class="fixed first">
    fixed first
</div>
<div class="fixed second">
    fixed second
</div>
<div class="fluid third">
    fluid third
</div>
```

CSS

```
.fixed {float:left; }

.first {width:100px; height:100px; background-color:#ccc;}
.second {width:100px; height:100px; background-color:#ddd;}

.fluid { float:none;  padding-left:200px; background-color:#eee; height:100px;}
```

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a9jbq5bj/4/)

**Update based on comments** (changes only in CSS)

```
.fixed {float:left; }

.first {width:100px; height:100px; background-color:#ccc; margin-right:10px;}
.second {width:100px; height:100px; background-color:#ddd; margin-right:10px;}

.fluid { float:none;  margin-left:220px; background-color:#eee; height:100px;}
```

This concept can also wotk with `margin` instead of `padding`. So you can do the following. I have added some margin to implement the space between the divs. The margin that the fixed divs should be added to the `margin-left` of the fluid div.

Here is the updated [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a9jbq5bj/4/) in a jsfiddle.

In your [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xGENxd) you just need to add `.fluid { margin-left: 220px; }` as you can see [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xGENRX).

Comment: I think the padding-right of 300px makes the (definitely correct) solution looks a bit messed up when looking at it on small screens (just had a look at it). (just put up the same in a codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wazOLP )

Comment: @j.bearGraphics That's a good point, I  had the window full screen and didn't even notice. I adjusted my example with smaller widths

Comment: This looks like it leads to the right solution. I have put your code added by my adaption here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xGENxd What I want to do is a navigation footer. There should be white space between the columns, could not get this done with your example. Any ideas how to adapt this?

Comment: My answer at the bottom is different to the one up here. anyway: two solutions: add a whitespace by adding divs inbetween with having a width equal to the whitespace you want, OR, use the holy grail layout I added... ;)

Comment: @merlin One clarification. I used in my first answer `padding-right` where the correct would be `padding-left`. I have updated my answer to be correct.

Comment: @merlin For your example now, I believe that your issue is not to have the background color of the fluid div in the margins of the fixed divs. For that case, you can safely use `margin-left` instead of `padding-left`. I updated my answer with a simple demo and I updated your codepen so that you also see it in your example

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the same solution used for the "Holy Grail Layout" (two sidebars sticking on the left and right and a fluid column in the middle). It also works if used with more than one column on the left and no column on the right:

EDIT: the stackoverflow answer is built for a grid, I changed it slightly to fit it for my needs (fixed/fixed/fluid/fixed)... as soon as I find it, I will post the edited solution!

[CSS fluid columns, fixed margins; the holy grail of holy grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7190768/css-fluid-columns-fixed-margins-the-holy-grail-of-holy-grails)
(This link provides a full explanation including an example)

Another example is this version by Matthew James Taylor:
http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/ultimate-3-column-holy-grail-pixels.htm

You can even put a fluid column in the first place, or in the middle by using this layout.

Comment: This mitght be a good solution for a website layout. I am looking for a navigation layout with fixed,fixed,fluid.