# HTML+CSS: Equal distance between footer nav elements without using table

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fluid width with equally spaced DIVs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865194/fluid-width-with-equally-spaced-divs)

I am trying to put footer elements which are texts. I was trying to have equal distance between texts elements.

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a>Item Reg</a></li>
    <li><a>Item Sm</a></li>
    <li><a>Item Very Long</a></li>
    <li><a>Item Reg</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Here is an image explaining the scenario I want to implement. Left and right elements are always aligned to left and right respectively.
[image: Expected Footer Element Behaviour]

How can I do it with css and html. NOTE: CSS3 is allowed.

Comment: Actually i found similar issue answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8724665/flexible-horizontal-navigation-with-equal-distance-between-nav-elements and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865194/fluid-width-with-equally-spaced-divs   ... thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

You ca use a padding-left for each `<li>` something like this:

```
    li{
position:relative;
float:left;
padding-left:20px;}
```

Comment: and increase the number of pixels in the padding until your right hand side touches the extremity.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use percentage points for widths.

```
ul {
  width: 100%;
}
ul li {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 25%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it in this way

```
<div class="footer">

    <div style="width:200px; float:left;">

        <ul style="list-style:none">
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
        </ul>

    </div>

    <div style="width:200px; float:left;">

        <ul style="list-style:none">
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
        </ul>

    </div>

    <div style="width:200px; float:left;">
        <ul style="list-style:none">
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
        </ul>

    </div>

    <div style="clear:both"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: thanx GvS now i got it how to do ..:-)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a fixed number of elements simply use :

```
ul{
    padding:0 20px 0 20px;
    width:100%;
}

li{
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    width:25%;
}

<ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
</ul>
```