# Table with fixed header and column - IE8 optimization

Tags: css, html

I have created layout that looks like this:
[image: layout mockup]

This is how it works:

[image]

As You can see header is fixed but scrollable, the same behaviour is for 1 column.

Here is code for this demo: **http://jsfiddle.net/Misiu/9j5Xy/7/**

Everything works fine, but only on FF, on IE8 I have 2 problems:

- In FF I have border in head and row divs (inside tables in them), but
  IE8 cuts the bottom border.

[image: ie error]

**UPDATE: Border error fixed (workaround) - I've added extra border to head, col and row divs.
http://jsfiddle.net/Misiu/9j5Xy/12/**

- Second problem is with scroll functionality-on FF everything works, but IE8 as always has problems. When I click inside wrapper div and use arrows to scroll my table div, FF works fine, but IE sometimes scrolls randomly or returns to top (try pressing arrow randomly). It should allow only one move at time.

---

Could someone help me with fixing this in IE and optimize code and css?

---

**I don't want to use any plugins like DataTables. In my case it is better to generate 4 tables on server than calling plugins on client-side-for very large tables and on older pc's it took almost 3 minutes to run DataTables with FixedColumn.**

Comment: I don't understand what this means: "I need this to be able to control row left and col top offset with scrollbars of table.".

Comment: I've updated my question to show what I want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to do all fixes with css and jQuery.
**http://jsfiddle.net/Misiu/9j5Xy/26/**

This is my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
function scrollHandler(e) {
    $('#row').css('left', -$('#table').get(0).scrollLeft);
    $('#col').css('top', -$('#table').get(0).scrollTop);
}
$('#table').scroll(scrollHandler);
$('#table').resize(scrollHandler);

var animate = false;
$('#wrapper').keydown(function (event) {
    if (animate) {
        event.preventDefault();
    };
    if (event.keyCode == 37 && !animate) {
        animate = true;
        $('#table').animate({
            scrollLeft: "-=200"
        }, "fast", function () {
            animate = false;
        });
        event.preventDefault();
    } else if (event.keyCode == 39 && !animate) {
        animate = true;
        $('#table').animate({
            scrollLeft: "+=200"
        }, "fast", function () {
            animate = false;
        });
        event.preventDefault();
    } else if (event.keyCode == 38 && !animate) {
        animate = true;
        $('#table').animate({
            scrollTop: "-=200"
        }, "fast", function () {
            animate = false;
        });
        event.preventDefault();
    } else if (event.keyCode == 40 && !animate) {
        animate = true;
        $('#table').animate({
            scrollTop: "+=200"
        }, "fast", function () {
            animate = false;
        });
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
});
```

But comments and optimizations are always welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at a framework like [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) or similar. Responsive/fluid layouts are in there working out of the box.

Comment: I know bootstrap and 960.gs, but all I need here is just a simple div not whole page. I will place that div inside an asp page, so hwole layout framework isn't needed, but thanks for tip :)

Comment: I've managed to do my layout :) but I get weird IE8 behavior. Could You help me with this?