# CSS multiple elements auto position

Tags: css, html, autoresize

I am working on a mobile website with four divs that need to be positioned according to the width of the parent div. I need the divs to divide up the space in between evenly. Here are a few examples:

When the width is 500px it might look something like this,

[image: img1]

and when it is 300px,

[image: img2]

Comment: Can you share your current attempts with us, tell us what you've tried so far (and perhaps why it didn't work for you)? This makes it a lot easier for us to help you!

Comment: wrap them in containers that are set to width 25%?

Comment: Thanks, should be able to get it to work now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following article: [Center Multiple DIVs with CSS](http://www.impressivewebs.com/center-multiple-divs/).

There is a [this similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865194/fluid-width-with-equally-spaced-divs) also.