# Evenly-horizontally distributed images of varied widths?

Tags: html, css, fluid-layout

I have 10 images that are the same height but different widths. I need to display them all in one line.. Is this possible? Also the widths are fluid for the container. Tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865194/fluid-width-with-equally-spaced-divs) but as my images aren't the same widths it doesn't seem to work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kept each image with a different percentage which gives the same effect.