# Navigation Bar is not inline at higher zoom

Tags: html, css, uinavigationbar

I have made a simple navigation bar but the list-items are not inline at a little higher zooms.

**HTML**

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Type 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Type 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Type 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Type 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

​
**CSS**

```
li{
display:inline;
float:left;
}

li a {
display:block;
width:155px;
text-align:center;
}    ​

ul {
background-color:#999999;
border:1px solid #006666;
height:25px;
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

Here is the fiddle for the code!

http://jsfiddle.net/CCCMC/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the width to make it fit will definitely work,
or you could try this (modified from: [Fluid width with equally spaced DIVs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865194/fluid-width-with-equally-spaced-divs))

**html:**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Type 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Type 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Type 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Type 4</a></li>
    <li class="stretch"></li>
</ul>
```

​

**CSS:**

```
li{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1    
}

li a {
    text-align:center;
    background-color:green;
}    

ul {
    background-color:#999999;
    border:1px solid #006666;
    height:25px;
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    text-align: justify;
    -ms-text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
    text-justify: distribute-all-lines;    
}

.stretch {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0
}
```

​

See it on JS fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/CCCMC/45/

This allows for different sizes/a different number of menu items.

(Remember to add the *zoom:1; *display:inline; fix for IE6/7 if you need it)

Comment: The fiddle is similar to mine!

Comment: Quite right, I forgot to update it with the changes, I've done it now, the link has been changed. Good spotting!.

Comment: Actually I have gone with a fixed-width navigation bar! BTW why have you used class stretch?

Comment: it forces the outer container to take up 100% of the width but still allows the internal elements to calculate their spacing based on it's width.

Answer (score 0):

just adjust the 'width:155px;' property for 'li a' selector. i checked the 125px value is looking good.

Answer (score 0):

this works: http://jsfiddle.net/CCCMC/3/

You defined the height of ul, when you zoom it doesn't fit on one line anymore. So I deleted the height, and used `display: inline-block` instead of `float: left` so you don't need to define the height anymore.

Just study the code, it's pretty much self-explanatory.

```
li{
    display:inline-block;
    width:155px;
    text-align:center;
}  

ul {
    background-color:#999999;
    border:1px solid #006666;
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```