# Equal spacing div's in a container

Tags: html, css, angularjs

Here is my example: http://jsfiddle.net/rtCP3/62/

I have 3 (or more!) div's I want to space equally in one container. When using angular with ng-repeat the styles are not being picked up. When I hardcode the exact same elements it works just fine.

Angular output:

```
<div class="container ng-scope" ng-controller="ParentCtrl">
     <!-- ngRepeat: item in list -->
     <div class="box ng-scope ng-binding" data-ng-repeat="item in list">item1</div>
     <div class="box ng-scope ng-binding" data-ng-repeat="item in list">item2</div>
     <div class="box ng-scope ng-binding" data-ng-repeat="item in list">item3</div>
     <div class="box ng-scope ng-binding" data-ng-repeat="item in list">item4</div>
     <span class="stretch"></span>
</div>
```

Hardcoded:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="box">Item 1</div>
    <div class="box">Item 2</div>
    <div class="box">Item 3</div>
    <div class="box">Item 4</div>
    <span class="stretch"></span>
</div>
```

I based this on this stackoverflow question: [Fluid width with equally spaced DIVs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865194/fluid-width-with-equally-spaced-divs)

Comment: I was able to make the boxes much closer together (without any other obvious issues) by removing the text justification CSS.

Comment: That's not what I want though, see the link to the other stackoverflow question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works. I'm not sure why, but it spaces it the same:

```
 <div class="container" ng-controller="ParentCtrl">
     <span data-ng-repeat="item in list">
         <div class="box">{{ item.name }}</div>
     </span>
     <span class="stretch"></span>
 </div>
```

Maybe someone else can explain why that works, but in your fiddle repeating on the span element but with the box class inside made both implementations look the same.

Comment: +1. I don't understand why this works / why it wasn't working to begin with but it solves the problem.

Comment: Matthew, remove your text justification CSS as well. Then it works: http://jsfiddle.net/wagedomain/wtWV6/

Comment: Here is the fiddle the I modified to test it out, http://jsfiddle.net/SC34z/ (Chrome Version 25.0.1364.97).

Comment: Ah, in the html you posted you didn't put the span class="Stretch" Can you add that in and i'll accept it?

Thanks a ton!

Comment: Sure. I actually removed the span = stretch from my fiddle and changed the CSS for the same effect, but I can add it back in.

Answer (score 1):

A comment in the SO question you reference says

> It took me 3h to find that you should have spaces between each boxes in the html. 'Justify' extends spaces between the elements and if your content is `<div/><div/><div/>` it does not work. You need to have `<div/> <div/> <div/>`.

I believe ng-repeat doesn't put any spaces between its output, so all the divs are right up against each other, causing the problem.

You could create your own ng-repeat-like directive that would add a space.

Comment: Wow... I never even thought to look at that. In my inspections of the dom I just saw them in the correct order. I'll keep this idea in the future.