# Make inline justified div into link (display: block does not work)

Tags: css, html, fluid-layout

I used the following solution to create 3 divs next to each other:
[Fluid width with equally spaced DIVs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865194/fluid-width-with-equally-spaced-divs)

However, when I wrap each box inside an `<a>` tag with `display:block` the entire layout gets funky.

Is there a way around this? The fluidity (is that even a word?) is not really necessary, but preferable. The reason I used it this solution is because it keeps boxes neatly next to each other even in IE6/7 and for the sake of simplicity too.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: !`div`s should not be inside `a` tags! Instead of this assign a click event handler to your divs and set the cursor to `pointer` in your css, you'll have the same effect.

Comment: try to put in jsfiddle.net ...

Comment: hmm an on click event would be a solution yes. Is that the best solution? In other words, "industry standard"?

Comment: try `display: table-cell;` instead of `display:block`

Comment: HTML5 _does_ allow you to wrap block-level elements in `<a>` tags, fyi. Although, that may not be what you're using. Please give a link to your example or create a jsfiddle, as we're having to make assumptions about what CSS changes you've made and they may be _wrong_ assumptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot wrap a `div` with `a` - and if I am understanding you correctly this is where your problems start.

If you want to make your entire `div` clickable, place a link inside your `div` around some text/a title/whatever and use jQuery to action this link if you click ANYWHERE inside the `div`

```
$(".divClass").click(function () {
    window.location = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
});
```