# CSS inline-block fixed width tiles

Tags: css, alignment

I'm building a tile-based portfolio Wordpress theme, and I can't get the tiles to center correctly in their parent div. [Here's the static page](http://wilson.cu.cc/) (I'm migrating from .cu.cc asap). I've used `inline-block` to align them all on one row, and there are `margin` styles to keep the gaps between the tiles, but what I'm getting is this (red lines added):

[image: Faulty Align]

I'd like to align the tiles flush to the red lines - how can I do it?

Here's a boiled down version of the HTML:

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
<div class="tile"></div>
<div class="tile"></div>
<div class="tile"></div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.content-wrapper{
width: 678px;
margin-top: 66px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
text-align: center;
}
.tile{
display:inline-block;
width: 182px;
height: 295px;
background-color: #e1e1e1;
border: solid 1px rgba(176,176,176,0);
margin-bottom: 64px;
margin-right: 35px
}
```

Thanks, Oliver

Comment: Can you just increase the right margin of the tiles?

Comment: @Explosion Pills That's what I would have thought, but it further buggers everything up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll add to Karl-André's answer by noting that `:last-child` is not supported in IE8, so it would be nice to switch to

```
.content-wrapper .tile {
   margin-left: 10px;
}
.content-wrapper .tile:first-child {
   margin-left: 0px;
}
```

Even more clever decision is to use the following:

```
.content-wrapper .tile + .tile {
   margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Just three lines instead of six, elegant and works everythere.

Also, if you're bored of manually typing margin and want `justify`-like behaviour, consider
[Fluid width with equally spaced DIVs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865194/fluid-width-with-equally-spaced-divs).

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this :

```
.tile:last-child{
    margin-right : 0;
}
```

You div are centered, but the last div margin is messing up the elements

Comment: Or, you can split the right margin by half, and use that value for equal horizontal margins :)

Comment: Thanks! But I tried adding that to `.tile`, but it has little effect.