# CSS auto margin in block to fit it width

Tags: html, css, sass

I have this HTML code:

```
<div class="link-area">
     <a href="/" id="parts">Автозапчасти</a>
     <a href="/catalogs/oil_mp" id="oils">Масла/автожидкости</a>
     <div class="oil-dd"></div>
     <a href="/catalogs/accums_mp" id="accums">Аккумуляторы</a>
     <a href="/catalogs/wheel_fixture_mp" id="wheel_fixtures">Крепёж</a>
     <div class="wheel_fixture-dd">     
     </div>
     <a href="/catalogs/wheel_fixture_mp" id="parts_for_service">Запчасти для ТО</a>
 </div>
```

and it looks like this:

[image]

but I must change it so, that between blocks in `link-area` div the margin is set to auto so that all this blocks are situated on all width of `link-area`:

[image]

How can I do this? Please see my [JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9tmZq/).

Comment: Have you tried `margin: 100%;`?

Comment: @rath for what you mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `text-align: justify;` on the container element.

Then stretch the content to take up 100% width

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/kAvaY/)**

### MARKUP

```
<div class="link-area">
     <a href="/" id="parts">Автозапчасти</a>
     <a href="/catalogs/oil_mp" id="oils">Масла/автожидкости</a>

     <a href="/catalogs/accums_mp" id="accums">Аккумуляторы</a>
     <a href="/catalogs/wheel_fixture_mp" id="wheel_fixtures">Крепёж</a>

     <a href="/catalogs/wheel_fixture_mp" id="parts_for_service">Запчасти для ТО</a>
 </div>
```

### CSS

```
div {
    text-align: justify;
}

div > a {
    display: inline-block;
    background: pink;
}

div:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

For further reference, check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6880421/703717) (which is also where I learnt this method from)

and also my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16310009/703717) which uses the css calc() function to achieve this effect.

Comment: In the future, questions that already have an answer on SO should be closed as duplicates, not have their solution copied to the duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

if number of orange boxes isn't variable just use margin like this:

**First Solution:**

```
.box{
    margin:0 15px 0 15px;
}
.box:first-child{
    margin:0 30px 0 0;
}
.box:last-child{
    margin:0 0 0 30px;
}
```

replace proper value instead of 15px and 30px

**Second Solution:**

```
.box{
    float:none !important;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.box:first-child{
    float:left;
    margin:0;
}
.box:last-child{
    float:right;
    margin:0;
}
```

Comment: why 15 why 30 etc ) ?   i see edit: proper value i could calculate, but it is bad

Comment: i dont have any idea to do this with one line of code but i have another way just wait and see the edit

Comment: see edit but i am not sure that work !!