# How to add a space after ng-repeat element?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

Using `ng-repeat` with `span` elements adds all `span` elements together w/o space between them thus making it an unbreakable line which does not wrap:

Code:

```
<span ng-repeat="label in labels">{{label}}</span>
```

renders html:

```
<span>label1</span><span>label 2</span><span>label3</span><span>label 3</span><span>label5</span><span>label 4</span>
```

This does not wrap in a narrow div.

Question: how to make it wrap?

http://jsfiddle.net/supercobra/6e8Bn/

Comment: I don't see how that example relates...

Comment: @elclanrs fiddle updated.

Comment: What if you add the space inside the `span` like `{{label}} `. That should wrap around http://jsfiddle.net/6e8Bn/4/

Comment: @elclanrs didn't see your comment -- apparently we were thinking the same thing

Comment: I think this is a good question.  I wish I could be more help (coming from Knockout) I'm only now starting to look into Angular for comparisons.  It leads to the more fundamental questions: Can angular elements self-reference?  Is there a callback on `ng-repeat`?  If either of these questions are yes, it'd be easy to insert a space after the element, especially with a library like jQuery.  Otherwise, you may want to consider a different workaround.

Answer (score 34):

I have the same problem only with a tags... Here was my solution:

```
<span ng-repeat-start="label in labels" ng-bind="label"></span> <span ng-repeat-end></span>
```

Basically anything between ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end will be repeated, including whitespace... Unfortunately, this meant using an extra span tag. Not ideal...

Comment: I wish I could give you all the points.  `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end` are probably the answer that would help the most people.

Comment: and why not ng-repeat="label in labels" ng-bind="label + ' '"

Answer (score 15):

I solved the problem nicely with css. Just change the span to `display:inline-block` and it will wrap properly.

However, in my specific situation this didn't work. I needed the space so that the elements would behave properly when `text-align:justify` was applied to them (evenly spacing them in the parent). So I made a directive:

```
angular.module('whatever')
.directive('addASpaceBetween', [function () {
        'use strict';
        return function (scope, element) {
            if(!scope.$last){
                element.after('&#32;');
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

and then in the html:

```
<span data-ng-repeat="(id, thing) in things" data-add-a-space-between>stuff</span>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted solution. Works like a charm and very elegant. I would just use '&#32;' instead of '&nbsp;' since NBSP is "non breakable" and will prevent inline (not inline-block) elements from breaking apart.

Comment: agree with Tom about `non-breaking` is non-breaking ;)

Comment: Thanks @Tom you're right. It worked for me because I was just spacing one line. It might not allow wrapping using non-breaking space, though I haven't actually tested that. I'm also trusting that your space character code works since I haven't tested that either.

Answer (score 8):

My solution is (note the space character after inner span):

```
<span ng-repeat="gate in gates"><span class="label label-info">{{gate}}</span> </span>
```

Comment: There's not enough love for this simple but effective answer

Answer (score 5):

@Pavel's answer helped me, specifically using `ng-repeat` on a `<span>` for bootstrap labels. These need to have a trailing white space otherwise there's no space rendered between them. Doubling up the `span` so the `label label-default` class is not on the same `span` as the `ng-repeat` does the trick.

```
<span ng-repeat="value in values">
  <span class="label label-default">{{value}}</span>
</span>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gLmtyfj4/2/

Comment: It doesn't work. you need to add &nbsp; since most people probably will use a html minifier...

Answer (score 4):

Here are a few different approaches:

## HTML

You could use the browser's native wrapping feature, which wraps when white-space is encountered.  To enforce it, manually insert a space after the value ([see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6e8Bn/5/)):

```
<span ng-repeat="label in labels">{{label}} </span>
```

---

## CSS

An alternative is to use some CSS tricks:

1. Insert white-space via CSS after each span:

   ```
   span:after{content:" "}
   ```
2. Floating the Spans

   a. If [div styling/border **IS NOT** important](http://jsfiddle.net/6e8Bn/35/):

   ```
   span { float:left; }
   ```

   b. If [div styling/border **IS** important](http://jsfiddle.net/6e8Bn/36/), also change *display* of div:

   ```
   div { display:inline-block; }
   span { float:left; }
   ```

   *Note: wrapping won't occur unless there is a width restriction on the div*

Comment: Odd that this is the only answer downvoted when it is the only one that addresses the OP's question. ::::  The other answers only insert newlines after each element, whereas this will keep them on the same line until it reaches the end of the container and seemlessly wrap.

Comment: OP have asked about space between spans. Not in spans.

Comment: @OlegGolovanov no. This is old question, but read the question and not the title. He wants what can't be done, or what I don't know how to do. This is the only workaround I found at the time.

Comment: @OlegGolovanov sorry, I was a bit busy to go into detail, the main thing is that whitespace will wrap elements like text in a paragraph.  Yes, he wanted a space after the `<span />` but wanted to use angular to do so -- easy to do with jQuery, but  I was (and still am) unsure how to do with Angular.  Please refer to my comment under the question.  But it seems like Torrance may have come up with another workaround.  I haven't done much with Angular since, but the question remains if an Angular object can self-reference.

Answer (score 1):

If vol7ron's response doesn't work, you may display spans inline and add margin right to them.

Here's the fiddle - [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6e8Bn/7/)

```
span {display:inline-block; margin-right:2px;}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ng-class` and add a class for all but the last element.

```
<span ng-repeat="label in labels"
      ng-class="{space:!$last,last:$last}">{{label}}</span>
```

and

```
span.space:after {
    // content: ', '; // I like comma separated
    content: ' ';
}
```

Here is the fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/dnozay/d3v6vq7w/

Answer (score 0):

```
<span ng-repeat="label in labels">{{label}}<br/></span>
```

or

```
<div ng-repeat="label in labels">{{label}}</div>
```

Comment: Thank you but I really don't want <br> or <div> as I want the labels to be looking like a one line or more that wraps like normal text.

Comment: @user198313 If you see the spacing between lines if you use `br`, then it should be some css defined in the html. In theory, `br` will not create any newline space.

Answer (score 0):

That's more of a style problem, not a logic one.
Maybe the following can help you:

```
<div><span ng-repeat="label in labels">{{label}}</span></div>
```

If you need further styling to make it fit into your app, try clarifying your question, but I hope you get the point.

Answer (score 0):

Vol7ron's answer is acceptable otherwise you can add a space into the end of the data elements.  Really does this have a real world use case?

http://jsfiddle.net/6e8Bn/6/

You can see I did a couple of spans outside of any angular based context and the same behavior is exhibited.  Apparently as the browser renders a single word on a line and doesn't do hyphenated breaking of words across lines if there is no space it simply continues onward to the right.

```
<span>I'm</span><span>not</span><span>even</span><span>angular</span><span>and</span><span>I</span><span>don't</span><span>wrap</span>
```

Javascript spaces added to data:

```
$scope.labels=["alongwooooooooord ", "alongwooooooooord2 ", "alongwooooooooord3 ", "ealongwooooooooord5 ", "falongwooooooooord5 "];
```

So ultimately the issue here isn't angular or anything related to the repeat but just how browsers interpret this.

Answer (score 0):

What you looking for is the `&nbsp;` or `&#160;` tag. This option works well if you plan to minify your HTML later with a gulp task or something similar.

```
<span ng-repeat="word in words">
    <span class="label label-success">{{word}}</span>&nbsp;
</span>
```

This way the space will show properly even if your html code is minified.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following method, it'll get the job done without a directive.

```
<div ng-repeat="label in labels">{{label}} <span ng-if="!$last"> </span></div>
```