# How to create a space between angular ng-repeated divs in jade?

Tags: angularjs, pug, angularjs-ng-repeat

The code is:

```
.container
  my-directive(ng-repeat="item in items", item="item")
```

My goal is to use that space with justify to create an evenly spaced grid of an unknown number of divs.

Comment: This sounds like more of a CSS question.  You may want to edit your question to include the CSS tag so the experts there can help you with this.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue is with `ng-repeat`. Here's a jade solution:

```
.container
  my-directive(ng-repeat-start="item in items", item="item")
  span(ng-repeat-end) #{' '}
```

Here's an equivalent solution for HTML I found: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19507046/4760334