# Center multiple floating divs next to each other

Tags: css, html, css-float, centering

I'm supposed to make 3 `div`s sit next to each other. So I made a `div` and I've put three `div`s in, with this css style:

```
div.holder div {
  float: left;
  width: 250px;
  background-color: yellow;   

  /*margin-right:auto;  /**These did not help**/
  margin-left:auto;  */
}
```

And html like this:

```
<div class="holder">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

And it's supposed to look like this:
[image: three divs]
And instead, it looks like this:
[image: three divs]

The border `div`s should be aligned with the ending of the grey line.

Comment: If you want your "gold div" sticked to the right, the make it `float: right`.

Comment: @Brewal That's a great idea. Now if you know a way to put the silver one in the middle, I'd be done with it. Maybe I'll try `margin:auto`.

Comment: The following thread has exactly what you're looking for [Fluid width with equally spaced DIVs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865194/fluid-width-with-equally-spaced-divs)

Comment: oh - I'm sorry, I couldn't figure out the correct query to search.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are specifying a pixel value for your width. No matter what you do with your floats, those pixel values are fixed and will never reach the end of the border. What you can do is set the width to a percentage like `width: 33%;`. You could also set your left and right margins to space out your divs like `margin: 0 20px;`.

What I typically do in these situations is wrap my elements in a div and use that div for positioning the elements. Then, the inner container I will use for background colors, text colors, etc. Something like that may work for you:

```
<div class="holder">
  <div class="wrapper">
     <div class="container">...</div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
     <div class="container">...</div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
     <div class="container">...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    float:left;
    width:33%;
}
.container {
    background-color: yellow;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bWFS8/

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to have them all aligned horizontally then you should really use an unordered list styled to display inline block with `zoom:1` and `display:inline`.

There is no reason to use a float to position these all side by side.

Answer (score 0):

Thats what I use when I want divs next to each other:

CSS:

```
#menuitem {
font-weight:bold;
border-right-style:solid;
font-size:10.7px;
border-right-width:1px;
border-left-width:1px;
height:30px;
position:relative;
}

#menuitem span {
position:absolute;
text-align: center;
}

#menubar {
margin-top:10px;
position:absolute;
left:0px;
font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="menubar">
<div style="float:left;width:104px;border-left-style:solid;" id="menuitem"><span style="bottom:9px;width:104px;">Menu Item 1</span></div>
<div style="float:left;overflow:hidden;width:78px;" id="menuitem"><span style="bottom:7px;width:78px;">Menu Item 2</span></div>
<div style="float:left;overflow:hidden;width:100px;" id="menuitem"><span style="bottom:9px;width:100px;">Menu Item 3</span></div>
</div>
```

Hope I helped.