# WordPress: Add empty list-item to navigation menu

Tags: php, html, wordpress, list, menu

```
<ul id="menu-primary">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li><li class="stretcher"></li> /* add adjacent to the last menu item */
</ul>
```

I need to add `<li class="stretcher"></li>` adjacent to the last menu item exactly as shown, to the menu with `id="menu-primary"`.

(The reason is to remove the whitespace generated in some browsers. Similar to the first answer in this question: [Fluid width with equally spaced DIVs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865194/fluid-width-with-equally-spaced-divs/6880421#6880421))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd add it with a filter:

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_stretcher', 10, 2);
function add_stretcher($items, $args) {
  if ($args->theme_location == 'primary') {
    $items .= '<li class="stretcher"></li>';
  }
  return $items;
}
```

Comment: It's not working. Don't see anything added to the menu. It's not a primary menu registered to the theme, if that makes a difference, I just gave the menu name "primary".

Comment: Temporarily, try losing the "if", and just have `$items .= '<li class="stretcher"></li>'; return $items;` as the function body. I only added that so the stretcher li wouldn't be added to every menu.

Comment: Now I see it, but it's not adjacent to the last menu item (as shown above) in the markup.

Comment: Interesting -- perhaps try `$items = rtrim($items) . '<li class="stretcher"></li>';` instead of `$items .= '<li class="stretcher"></li>';` to get rid of any whitespace/linefeeds etc. on the existing items?

Comment: Now all that's left is to target this specific menu, but I could live without that.

Answer (score 0):

You can add it using jQuery with following code

```
<script>
   jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      jQuery("#menu-primary li").last().before("<li class="stretcher"></li>");                             
   });
</script>
```