# WordPress: add HTML to a specific nav menu

Tags: php, html, wordpress, menu, navigation

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_custom', 10, 2);
function add_custom($items, $args) {
  if ($args->theme_location == 'primary') {
    $items .= '<li class="custom"></li>';
  }
  return $items;
}
```

which produces:

```
<ul id="menu-top">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="custom"></li> /* added custom HTML */
<ul>
```

but what if my WP menu doesn't have a "theme_location"? Can I target my menu by id/class instead of "theme_location", or how else can I add HTML to one specific menu?

Comment: Assuming you're using the Appearance -> Menu editor, you could add a page, add a specific class to the page and hide it and what not with CSS.  I don't know what else you need from this though so that might not help.

Comment: I have a specific case, so I can't do that.  I simplified my question to avoid unnecessary complication, but more details of what I'm trying to do can be found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18658643/wordpress-add-empty-list-item-to-navigation-menu

Comment: why don't you add a theme location?

Comment: I was wondering if I could just simply use the menu's id/class instead.

I'd like to assign it a theme_location, so if I add ``register_nav_menu( 'primary', 'Primary Menu' );`` and assign my menu to 'Primary Menu', what else do I need to do?

Comment: I believe that would be all you have to do, but before that, have you tried checking the $args array to see if the id is included there?

Answer (score 1):

**Can you use jQuery?**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#menu-top').append('<li class="custom"></li>');
});
```

**Or PHP + CSS**  - with this solution, you add it to every menu and hide it if need be via CSS.

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_custom', 10, 2);
function add_custom($items, $args) { 
   $items .= '';
   return $items;
}
```

```
li.custom { display:none; } // hide originally
ul#menu-top li.custom { display:inline; } // or whatever styles
```

Comment: @Sunny I clearly don't know the actual answer, but I provided another solution you could use.

Answer (score 0):

When there is no theme_location, then I guess, it falls back to wp_page_menu. So, in theory, you could filter into `wp_page_menu` and modify the output.

```
<?php
//Use this filter to modify the complete output
//You can get an argument to optionally check for the right menu
add_filter( 'wp_page_menu', 'my_page_menu', 10, 2 );
/**
 * Modify page menu
 * @param  string $menu HTML output of the menu
 * @param  array $args Associative array of wp_page_menu arguments
 *                     @see http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_page_menu
 * @return string       menu HTML
 */
function my_page_menu( $menu, $args ) {
    //see the arguments
    //Do something with $menu
    return $menu;
}

//Use this filter to alter the menu argument altogether
//It is fired before creating any menu html
add_filter( 'wp_page_menu_args', 'my_page_menu_pre_arg', 10, 1 );
/**
 * Modify page menu arguments
 * @param  array $args Associative array of wp_page_menu arguments
 *                     @see http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_page_menu
 * @return array       modified arguments
 */
function my_page_menu_pre_arg( $args ) {
    //Do something with $args
    return $args;
}
```

Hope it helps.