# Jade not rendering fluid width equally spaced divs correctly

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, css, pug

I am currently in the process of moving a HTML5/CSS3/Javascript site I have been developing over to Node.js using express.js with Jade.

I have a container that holds fluid width, equally spaced `divs` (the `text-justify` method) that works great in plain HTML but when generated by Jade it fails to space them out (tested in chrome, firefox & opera). The confusing thing is that the rendered HTML and css properties are identical.

Plain HTML fiddle: http://fiddlesalad.com/html/fluid-column-layout-html-works

Jade Generated HTML fiddle: http://fiddlesalad.com/less/fluid-column-layout-jade-not-working/

It looks like `text-align: justify;` isn't working.... though I have no idea why.

I am new to Node.js, Express.js and Jade, so is it possible that my app.js or route handlers haven't been configured correctly (I used `express --session test` and `npm install` after updating my package.json to handle my depencies)?

Is there an alternative method of getting equally spaced, fluid divs that I can use (I have also tried this similar method: [Fluid width with equally spaced DIVs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865194/fluid-width-with-equally-spaced-divs))?

**app.js**:

```
    /**
     * Module dependencies.
     */

    var express = require('express');
    var routes = require('./routes');
    var user = require('./routes/user');
    var http = require('http');
    var path = require('path');

    var app = express();

    // all environments
    app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
    app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');
    app.use(express.favicon());
    app.use(express.logger('dev'));
    app.use(express.json());
    app.use(express.urlencoded());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(express.cookieParser('your secret here'));
    app.use(express.session());
    app.use(app.router);
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

    // development only
    if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
      app.use(express.errorHandler());
    }

    app.get('/', routes.index);

    http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
      console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
    });
```

**routes.js**
        /*
         * GET home page.
         */

```
    exports.index = function(req, res){
      res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow.  It turns out that the whitespace the pure HTML version has is the difference.  Your Jade gets rendered like so:

```
<div class="grid"><div class="column">Item 1</div><div class="column">Item 2</div><div class="column">Item 3</div><div class="column">Item 4</div><div class="column">Item 5</div></div>
```

but when you write it out manually, you get:

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="column">Item 1</div>
  <div class="column">Item 2</div>
  <div class="column">Item 3</div>
  <div class="column">Item 4</div>
  <div class="column">Item 5</div>
</div>
```

You could try setting pretty mode to true with something like `app.locals({pretty:true})` in your configuration, but then you lose the benefit of not having pretty set to true in production.

As to another method of achieving the same end, I don't have an answer for that at this time.

Comment: I would recommend spacing with css (padding/margin/etc.) not with white-space.

Comment: I agree.  I was just answering the question of why they render differently.

Comment: Great thank you! Can I ask why not to use whitespace?

Comment: Separation of structure and presentation.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like so long as there is *at least one character* between the `div`s in the raw markup, the spacing is correct. This workaround worked for me:

```
div.grid
  div.column Item 1
  .
  div.column Item 2
  .
  div.column Item 3
  .
  div.column Item 4
  .
  div.column Item 5
```

Since the `font-size` of `.grid` is `0`, the periods are not visible.