# How to equally space images horizontally in div?

Tags: css

How can I place images like follow :

[image]

I would like the spaces between the images to be the same. Also while resizing the window, I would like the spaces to update so that each space always has the same size.

```
<div id="panel">
    <img id="icon1" class="icon" src="...">
    <img id="icon2" class="icon" src="...">
    <img id="icon3" class="icon" src="...">
</div>
```

Here is what I have :
http://jsfiddle.net/eBLgP/2/

It looks a lot like this post : [Fluid width with equally spaced DIVs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865194/fluid-width-with-equally-spaced-divs?rq=1)

But it's not the same, I would like spaces also between the right and left side of the div. Also the example above seems quite complicate to me.

Comment: Did you have any chance to take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865194/fluid-width-with-equally-spaced-divs?rq=1

Comment: Do you want it with a fixed width? or a fluid with?

Comment: @CTravel I would like it to be automaticaly spaced so that it's still correctly spaced while resizing.

Comment: @HashemQolami I have seen that question, that's not what I want and I didn't succeed to change the css as I want it.

Comment: Is there always only 3 images, and are they always the same size ?

Comment: Could be more than 3. The space between each images and the border right and left of the div must adapt. Images are all the same size.

Comment: are the images loaded from a static or dynamic source? if you want to add the same spacing, you also need to stretch the container, and that could be performed in a more easy way by javascript, not pure css

Comment: Hm... Images are loaded statically I guess. They are loaded in the HTML. If there are more images, I'll add them on my HTML with the tag `<img>` like the others. The css could change in this case, I could change some of my css in the same time, but if it could be automatic, it would be cool. Like when using percentage or `auto`.

Comment: Edit question, I changes the illustration.

Comment: Sorry I didn't have connection on the road... is this something like what you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/eBLgP/6/ since you said you didn't want javascript you'll have to manually adjust the wrapper and images with to make them fit as long as you add or remove images

Comment: @JuanCarlosAlpizarChinchilla Exactly !! =) But is there no other way than this trick ?

Comment: Using just css there's I can't think in a way to short the margin or enlarge the image width without knowing how many items you'll get, however javascript works once the DOM is ready, you could alter CSS of those there cause you know how many images will be loaded exactly and calculate those margins and widths.

Comment: I mean I would have prefer just use css on `<img>` and not add a `<div>` container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/eBLgP/5/

final code, with responsive behavior:

```
#panel {
border: 2px solid blue;
    overflow: auto;
}

.icon-container {
    float: left;
    width: 33.3%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

when you make elements float you can sort them all in the same line and same orientation as long as they're floating in the same direction, however for the parent container (panel div in this case) to recognize the height of containing elements you need overflow property, so add

`overflow: auto;`

Now you can add a div to contain the images, because using a width directly on images would alter the image dimensions and that's not what is intended.

Once you got floating div elements, you can spread them with a percentage based with, granting all of them will have the same space inside your container, doesn't matter how big or small the screen becomes .

The only thing left is to center images inside their parent containers, since divs are block display by default, you can use `text-align: center` to grant all of the children elements of parent (the images in this case) will be centered

Comment: In your solution, the spaces are not dynamic, but it's not a problem, I could change the css by hand in your case if I had to add or remove images. The problem in your solution is that the spaces are not all the same. It's quite like what I want, but not exactly. I would like all the spaces to be the same. (between each image and the right and left border of the div)

Comment: If you want the space to be dynamically calculated you should make it via js not pure css

Comment: When I say dynamically I mean not using `px` or `em`. Isn't it possible with percentage, `auto`, `align`, `position` or anything else ?

Comment: It's not exactly what I wanted, but it's the closest result I found.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by using text-align:justify and adding 1 line on bottom like this :
http://jsfiddle.net/26CLe/1/

```
#panel {
    border: 2px solid blue;
    text-align:justify ;
}

#panel:after {
    content:'';
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
}
```

The only problem is that it add a little line on bottom, but justification is okay.
This solution came from here :
http://yidille.free.fr/plux/valign/?69-text-align-justify-sur-derniere-ligne-et-centrage-de-boites

Comment: That's more like what I'm looking for, the thing is that in your example, there are no margins on the left and right sides.

Comment: in the sample given in your question the images have margins on both sides... can you be more specific on what are you looking for?

Comment: Yeah i understand what you mean, if you want exactly the same width on left/right and between images it can be hard, but you can had padding on #panel like this : http://jsfiddle.net/26CLe/2/
What do you know exactly ? Is there always 3 elements on the line ? Are each elements always same width ? Does it have to fit on multiple lines (like 20 images on XX lines) ?

Comment: if I get this clear, my reply above can be an option on what Elfayer is looking for, if no margins in first and last image are required @PierreGranger is a good solution, Elflayer can you check both answers (Pierre and mine) and tell us if something of those are what you're looking for?

Comment: In fact the question is : is there only 3 images and are they always same width. If yes, your solution is really better. If no (like 4, 5 images) or if images could be different width, it's gonna be much more difficult..

Comment: Currently there are 3 images, but could be more. I'd like a CSS that places the images whith the same space between each other AND the borders right and left of the div. Images are always 64x64 in reality, it won't move, and they all are the same size.

Comment: can the panel size adjust according the amount of images or should it be a fixed size?