# Variable Number of Divs Equally Spaced Vertically in a Container Div

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I am looking to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865194/fluid-width-with-equally-spaced-divs) but do it vertically instead of horizontally. I have already tried the solution [here](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/dynamic-vertical-centering/) but I want the child divs to equally space over the entire height of the container div - that solution only centers the divs without expanding the space in between them to use the entire height of the container.  I am willing to use Javascript, but would prefer an HTML/CSS only solution.  I've looked briefly into the flexbox, but I was scared off by backwards compatibility issues.

Some basic code:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="1" class="child"></div>
    <div id="2" class="child"></div>
    <div id="3" class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Should render with div1 at the extreme top of the parent, div 2 at the extreme bottom of the parent, and div3 centered in the middle, and ideally I could add a variable number of additional child divs and the spacing would automatically adjust.

Any suggestions? Should I just use the flexbox and not worry about supporting older browsers?

Comment: I think you can currently only do this with flexbox. Otherwise the closest you'll get is with css tables http://jsfiddle.net/brxpv/1/ - but that's not really the effect you want

Answer (score 0):

I have worked with javascript. my javascript code is

```
function cssFunction(){
            var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("child")
            var len = elem.length;
            for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
                elem[i].style.height =200/len;
            }
        }
```

and the css is

```
div#parent{
  max-height: 200px;
  width : 500px;
  padding : 0px;
  margin : 0px;
 }

.child{
    border:2px solid #a1a1a1;
    width : 93%;
    margin : 5% 0%;
    height : 100%;
 }
```

and Html is

```
<body onload="cssFunction()">
    <div id="parent">
        <div id="d1" class="child">Vertical alignment</div>
        <div id="d2" class="child">Vertical alignment</div>
        <div id="d3" class="child">Vertical alignment</div>
        <div id="d4" class="child">Vertical alignment</div>
        <div id="d5" class="child">Vertical alignment</div>
        <div id="d6" class="child">Vertical alignment</div>
        <div id="d7" class="child">Vertical alignment</div>
        <div id="d8" class="child">Vertical alignment</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you could probably do something like this:

**HTML**

```
<div id='parent'>
    <div id='1' class='child'></div>
    <div id='2' class='child'></div>
    <div id='3' class='child'></div>
</div>
```

---

**CSS**

```
.child {
    height: 30%;
    margin: 0;
}

#parent {
    height: 90%;
}
```

---

Using percentages is an easy way to fill things, such as your div `#parent`, though you could also use whatever units you like.
Hope this helped.

Comment: No. If you read the question, you will see that the solution needs to respond to a variable number of child divs, which this approach does not do.

Comment: Well then, sorry I couldn't help, there's probably a way to do do it... maybe if you just specify the width? That would just set the width, the height would just automatically adjust.