# having trouble positioning my divs next to each other

Tags: css, html

I have been reading a few different answers to this type of question, as well as researching a bit on how to fix it, but I feel that my code is probably pretty messed up by now. I can't get my divs to sit next to each other so that I can create another larger div beneath them. I am very new at this and have been following tutorials and class reading to get this far, so I am sure something fairly simple or dumb is wrong. I just can't figure it out :-/. Here is the jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/betyB/1/

CSS:

```
body {
    background-image: url(superhighway.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-attachment:scroll;
    background-color:#000000;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
#main1 {
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color:#000;
    margin: 5px;
    border: solid 4px #323232;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow:hidden;
    filter:alpha(opacity=50);
    -moz-opacity:.50;
    opacity:.50;
}
#content1 {
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
    top:-425px;
    width: 960px;
    height: 800px;
    text-align:left;
    color:#FFF;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 35px;
}
#main2 {
    position:top;
    z-index:1;
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color:#000;
    border: solid 4px #323232;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top:300px;
    filter:alpha(opacity=50);
    -moz-opacity:.50;
    opacity:.50;
}
#content2 {
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
    top:-425px;
    width: 960px;
    height: 800px;
    text-align:left;
    color:#FFF;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 35px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Title Here</title>
    <link href="MyStyle.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--
    <script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    alert("");

    </script>
    -->
</head>
<body>
    <h1>My Ideal Job</h1>

    <div id="main1"></div>
    <div id="content1">
        This is to test the content of the div.
        <li>one</li>
        <li>two</li>
        <p></p>
        <li>a</li>
        <li>b</li>
    </div>

    <div id="main2" style="float:right;margin:0;"></div>
    <div id="content2">
        Testing number two div.
        <li>one</li>
        <li>two</li>
        <p></p>
        <li>a</li>
        <li>b</li>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, vlund! Welcome to StackOverflow! One of the things that is often helpful when asking questions like this is to provide a jsfiddle of your code, so that we can see exactly what is going on. Check out http://www.jsfiddle.net, copy and paste your code in the appropriate spots, save the fiddle and add a link to the fiddle to your post. Good luck and happy coding! :)

Comment: Also, try to make your code as easily readable as possible, by formatting it for one thing. I will do that for now.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that you need to do is add the `display: inline-block;` property to your `div`s' CSS. Second, you may need to ensure that there is a whitespace (either via just adding a space or adding `&nbsp;` if that is not sufficient, in your `div`s.

**Extra Info**

Positioning `div`s can be very simple, or it can be very challenging depending on your implementation and what you are trying to achieve. Most of the time, when speaking generally about positioning `div`s side-by-side the simple answer is to use the `display:inline-block` property. However, if you are trying to space everything out evenly and provide the maximum amount of cross-browser support, the solution gets more complicated.

Check out this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6880421/1506793)**. It provides a terrific description of the challenges and various solutions to positioning `div`s side-by-side with maximum cross-browser support. The post is primarily concerned with evenly spacing the `div`s, which you can decide to do or not to do, but it provides a lot of great background and extra info that you should know. I have used the described solution for over a dozen implementations.

Here is the code for that solution:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="box1"></div>
    <div class="box2"></div>
    <div class="box3"></div>
    <div class="box4"></div>
    <span class="stretch"></span>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#container {
    border: 2px dashed #444;
    height: 125px;

    text-align: justify;
    -ms-text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
    text-justify: distribute-all-lines;

    /* just for demo */
    min-width: 612px;
}

.box1, .box2, .box3, .box4 {
    width: 150px;
    height: 125px;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1
}
.stretch {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0
}

.box1, .box3 {
    background: #ccc
}
.box2, .box4 {
    background: #0ff
}
```

---

And here is a link to the fiddle that he provided: http://jsfiddle.net/EDp8R/3903/

Answer (score 0):

ok so I made this pen for you:  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zpxJt it does what I think you want, but your html has several errors, missing

you shouldn't be doing inline styles, I understand you're new to this so I get it. The layout you want to achieve can be difficult if your html structure is not correct.