# How to Distribute 24 Divs Evenly (3 Columns 8 Rows)

Tags: html, css

So I have this problem distributing the 24 Divs evenly. I have a container that should have 3 columns and 8 rows. I followed the css styles here:

[Fluid width with equally spaced DIVs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865194/fluid-width-with-equally-spaced-divs)

it works perfectly but there is a little problem at the bottom. it seems the last row is not working exactly what it supposed to be:

here's an image to describe the problem.

[image]

Notice that at the bottom, the divs are **NOT** distributed **EVENLY.** I wonder what's wrong because all the 7 rows is functioning correctly (distributed evenly) but the problem lies at the last row.

here's my HTLML & CSS and [my Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bendaggers/ougntvvf/3/)

```
<div id="container">
<div class="box"> </div>
<div class="box"> </div>
<div class="box"> </div>
<div class="box"> </div>
<div class="box"> </div>
<div class="box"> </div>
<div class="box"> </div>
<div class="box"> </div>
<div class="box"> </div>
<div class="box"> </div>
<div class="box"> </div>
<div class="box"> </div>
<div class="box"> </div>
<div class="box"> </div>
<div class="box"> </div>
<div class="box"> </div>
<div class="box"> </div>
<div class="box"> </div>
<div class="box"> </div>
<div class="box"> </div>
<div class="box"> </div>
<div class="box"> </div>
<div class="box"> </div>
<div class="box"> </div>
</div>

#container {
    border: 2px dashed #444;
    height: auto;

    text-align: justify;
    -ms-text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
    text-justify: distribute-all-lines;

    /* just for demo */
    width: 1023px;
}

.box {
    width: 327px;
    height: 320px;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1
}
#container:after {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0
}

.box {
    background: #ccc
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it by apply css `content: "";` property to your `div#container:after` tag.

The `text-align` to `#container` is [Justified](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align) but the last line (or row in your case) does not get stretched (or compressed) to fit in the `#container` and this solution use a variation of the `:after` pseudo-content method that will fix the issue.

### JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ougntvvf/10/)

**CSS:**

```
#container:after {
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0
}
```

Check this out for more info about CSS text-align property:

> [Mozilla MDN CSS text-align](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align)