# How to align div boxes responsive in html?

Tags: html, css

I have tried to get responsive design for div boxes. But couldn't get it.

I got output like this..

[image]

When I tried to expand it, it is showing like this.

[image]

Couldn't get responsive one...

Tried with ctrl+shift+m in firefox.

Here is my code

index.html

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
.tab_list_common{
font-family: Arial; 
font-size: 13px; 
font-weight: bold;
color: #666666; 
line-height: 1.3;
border: 1px solid #000000;
 display: inline-block; 
}
.com_div{
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
}
.outer{
border: 1px solid #000000;
line-height: 50px;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="outer">
<div class="com_div">
<span class="tab_list_common">$1.00</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<span class="tab_list_common">$2.00</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<span class="tab_list_common">$3.00</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<span class="tab_list_common">$4.00</span>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 'Responsive' just means adapting to different media and resolutions. Seems to be doing that just fine. If it's not working how you want it to, be more specific in describing it than 'I want it to be responsive', that's akin to saying "I want a car that drives" and expecting us to guess which brand and model you want.

Comment: when u give display: inline block; it will expand the content of the div box. but in my case, it is not expanding, instead it is displaying center

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to display them as `inline-block`, eliminate white spacing between them and set `width` to: (total width / elements).

Setting `box-sizing: border-box;` would include borders in width calculation.

**Edit:** Added spacing between divs using margin.

```css
.tab_list_common{
  font-family: Arial; 
  font-size: 13px; 
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #666666; 
  line-height: 1.3;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%; /* total width / elements */
  margin: 0 2.5%;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.com_div{
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
.outer{
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  line-height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="com_div">
   <span class="tab_list_common">$1.00</span><!--
--><span class="tab_list_common">$2.00</span><!--
--><span class="tab_list_common">$3.00</span><!--
--><span class="tab_list_common">$4.00</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need some spaces between each and every boxes..instead of using nbsp

Comment: if i give 20% width each when i tried with larger pixel it is not responsive

Comment: and one more thing, How can I make the div box as checked one? for example, If I select, $1.00 box it should display as red color border like border: 2px solid #(red hexa value)

Comment: I tried like this in css styles...tab_inv_dtval:checked{
border: 5px solid #FFFFFF;
}

Comment: You could make a css trick with checkbox + label or better use javascript for that.

Answer (score 1):

[Try this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TalkingRock/1o1cenzx/)

This technique uses `text-align:justify;` on the .outer div, which applies to the the inline-block elements.

CSS

```
.outer {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    width: 100%;
    text-align:justify;
    -ms-text-justify:distribute-all-lines;
    text-justify:distribute-all-lines;
    min-width:13em;  /* add this if you don't want the divs to wrap when the screen size is reduced */
}
.com_div {
    padding:.95em .95em 0em .95em;
    line-height:1;
}
.tab_list_common {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: .82em;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #666666;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
.stretch {
    width:100%;
    display:inline-block;
    font-size:0;
    line-height:0;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="outer">
<div class="com_div">
<span class="tab_list_common">$1.00</span>
<span class="tab_list_common">$2.00</span>
<span class="tab_list_common">$3.00</span>
<span class="tab_list_common">$4.00</span>
 <span class="stretch"></span>
</div>
</div>
```

It requires a span div at the bottom for stability, and the divs need to be on their own line, or have a space between the tags. For more useful justify centering techniques see this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865194/fluid-width-with-equally-spaced-divs).

Comment: Thanks:) The link is a great resource, and the various techniques come in handy for different situations.