# Fluid width with equally spaced DIVs (also from container)

Tags: css

I want to achieve this, using only HTML/CSS:

[image: equally spaced divs (also from container)]

Much like [this](http://css-tricks.com/equidistant-objects-with-css/) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865194/fluid-width-with-equally-spaced-divs/6880421#6880421), except that they must be equally spaced also from the container.

Comment: Have you tried something yet that hasn't worked?

Comment: I was actually trying some stuff until I came up with a solution, so I decided to post the question anyway, and then the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If the items you need the space between have a defined width and you don't need IE8 support, you can use calc() to do this (http://caniuse.com/#search=calc).

Just add the following margin-left to the child elements.

```
/* X = number of containers */
/* Y = container width (needs to be defined) */
/* Z = number of spaces (usually X + 1) */
margin-left: calc((100% - (X * Y)) / Z);
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/supah_frank/pen/OPMrvZ

Comment: Care to explain? I've never had any issues with calc() performance and have used it fairly extensively.

Comment: Simple and great solution.

Comment: A solution for using that with a dynamic number of elements would be to have a couple of classes like `.third {  margin-left: calc((100% - (3 * 100px)) / 4) }`, `.quarter {
    margin-left: calc((100% - (4 * 100px)) / 5)
}` and so forth...

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this, based on Bootstrap's grid:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="box"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="box"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="box"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="box"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS (SCSS)**

```
$gutter: 100px;

* { box-sizing: border-box; }

body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

.container {
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: $gutter/2;
  padding-right: $gutter/2;

  background: lightgrey;
  height: 75px;
}
.row {
  //margin-left: -$gutter/2;
  //margin-right: -$gutter/2;
}
.col {
  float: left;
  padding-left: $gutter/2;
  padding-right: $gutter/2;
  width: 25%;

  //border: 1px solid blue;
  background: lightgray;
  height: 50px;
}

.box {
  width: auto;
  background: red;
  height: 25px;
}
```

[Sample](http://codepen.io/isaacalves/pen/xbZmXZ?editors=110)

Comment: This doesn't work if I need to constraint the box width

Answer (score 0):

Here's one probably terrible way to do it.

```css
body { width:100%; border:solid 1px blue; margin:0; padding:0; }
div { background:red;
      height:60px;
      width:300px;
      display:inline-block;
      position:relative;
      margin-left:-225px;
}
div.a {left:25%;}
div.b {left:50%;}
div.c {left:75%;}
```

```html
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="c"></div>
```

Then adjust the (negative) `margin-left` value to 3/4 the `width` of your divs.

Comment: I had tried that! But with margin-left set to half of the width of the divs. But they won't be evenly distributed that way, even though it may seem so if they have very small width.

Comment: I updated my answer - margin needs to be set to 3/4 with of divs.