# White space after centering inline-block elements

Tags: html, css

```
.calloutWrapper 
{
background: green;
height: 50%;

text-align: justify;
-ms-text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
}

.callout {
width: 24%;
min-height: 100%;
vertical-align: top;
display: inline-block;
*display: inline;
zoom: 1;
background-color: blue; }


.stretch {
content: '';
width: 100%;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 0;
vertical-align: top;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yux07nom/

There is white space after the "callouts" seen with the blue backgrounds. This extends beyond the green background of "calloutWrapper" I believe its caused by the .stretch applied to the span.

Comment: I'm using Chrome as well -- If you scroll all the way down you'll notice that there is white space that extends beyond the blue boxes on the green background.

Comment: Definitely the .stretch. What are you trying to do with the stretch?

Comment: From what I understand this is used in conjunction with the code from .callout to automatically evenly space the div's it's applied to. I based the code off http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865194/fluid-width-with-equally-spaced-divs

Comment: From what I see, you are trying to align 4 boxes horizontally. Why don't just the boxes margin on the right of 2% and set the first box (:first-child) margin to 0

Comment: I don't see any issues in Chrome or Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Inline-block elements will preserve one space in the HTML. Two choices:

1. Have no space between those inline-block elements in the HTML.
2. `Float:left` those inline-block elements

Comment: The problem is not with the spacing between, but the spacing after.

Answer (score 0):

First off you close out the body twice which doesn't cause your problem but should be resolved

```
</body>
    <script>
    </script>
</body>
```

Then the white space is caused by your .stretch span
`display: inline-block;` is the culprit

Remove that and your good to go.
A bit more info about what you're trying to achieve with that span could help provide a better answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865194/fluid-width-with-equally-spaced-divs

Going for this -- but with no white space at the end

Comment: In your code the .callout divs are response, but in that link provided the widths are fixed, and attempting to space them evenly. You should try using a responsive grid css, like bootstrap or foundation, alternatively here is a simple one you could just add the CSS to your project then use it for your responsive divs - http://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/iGsJI

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to achieve responsive boxes you could use a css responsive grid template like [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) or [foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/).

Alternatively you could just float left and add margin right to the first 3 elements.

eg
http://jsfiddle.net/yux07nom/5/

```
<div class="calloutWrapper">
    <div class="callout">Callout</div>
    <div class="callout">Callout</div>
    <div class="callout">Callout</div>
    <div class="callout last">Callout</div>
</div>
```

And the CSS

```
.callout {
    width: 24%;
    min-height: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    float:left;
    margin-right:1.3333333333%;
}

.callout.last{
    margin-right:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there's an ideal solution to this. Your best bet is to set the font size of the `.calloutWrapper` div to zero and then reapply a useful font-size value to the `.callout` divs, like this : http://jsfiddle.net/2dgx98ye/

Note however, that some older browsers, particularly some used on mobiles, try to apply a minimum font-size which breaks this. In modern browsers, even when the have a minimum font-size configured, do not enforce it on elements where the font-size is 0.