# CSS table width

Tags: html, css, css-tables

There is [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hxxeshat/11/)

```
.content {
    width: 1140px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
.content .content_row {
    display: table;
}
```

I want justify my two rows to 1140px.
Can I do this without table-tag?

UPD. I want this [result](http://keepfoto.ru/view/2be0/1oPiv6)

Answer (score 0):

try the following

```
.content {
    min-width: 1140px; // Change to min-width
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
.content .content_row {
    display: table;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hxxeshat/17/)**

```
.content {    
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center; // Removed width from .content
}
.content > .content_row {
    display: table;
    width: 1140px; // Added width here
}
```

Comment: My table cells should be have width equal width of images(

Comment: i dont get what you are telling, if possible create your expected result as a image

Comment: check this link, might be helpful for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865194/fluid-width-with-equally-spaced-divs

Comment: thx, but its dont help me coz my table-cells dont have fixed width... or 215px, or 345px

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,

```
.content .content_row {        
    border-spacing:10px
}
```

[See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UI_Designer/vegLxt64/1/)