# How to make an equal distance between elements footer?

Tags: html, css

I have this site:

http://www.les-toiles.co/

In the footer of the site I have 3 items ("contact info","customer care","about us","social media").

How do I do to have an equal distance between these elements?
I've tried to modify the CSS code but unfortunately we did.
I posted a section of code that I have no idea who would be best suited for this problem.
I would ask if you can inspect least CSS code and give me advice please.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fluid width with equally spaced DIVs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865194/fluid-width-with-equally-spaced-divs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class='footer'> 
      <div class='footer-box'> 
      </div>
      <div class='footer-box'> 
      </div>
      <div class='footer-box'> 
      </div>
</div>
```

.footer-box
    {
      width: 33.33%;
      float: left;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      padding: 20px;
    }