# Div height to fit its content

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have some css and html code to uniformly separate the buttons (or group of buttons). Justification works great but for some reason the container div `.justified` height is notably taller than its contents.

[image]

Why this happens? I want it to be the same height as the buttons. How can i do it? (I have a [jsfiddle that shows my problem](http://jsfiddle.net/nacho4d/usqp2qxf/) equivalent to the following code)

```css
/* Approach based on these two: */
/* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865194/ */
/* http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/EDp8R/ */
div.justified {
    text-align: justify;
    -ms-text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
    text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
    border: thin solid purple;
}
div.justified > div {
    border: thin solid green;
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
}
div.justified div.spacer {
    width: 1px;
    display: inline-block;
}
div.justified > span.stretch {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;
}
```

```html
<br/>
<br/>
example 1:
<div class='justified'>
    <div>
        <button>button1</button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button>button2</button>
    </div>
    <span class='stretch'></span>
</div>
example 2:
<div class='justified'>
    <div class='spacer'></div>
    <div>
        <button>button1</button>
    </div>
    <span class='stretch'></span>
</div>
```

Comment: why display:inline-block to span 'stretch'? is it requirement? the issue is due to that only. If you use display: block it will work fine

Comment: @nacho4d stretch span makes , what it contains.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple with `flexbox`, no extra divs or spans.

```css
div.justified {
  border: thin solid purple;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class='justified'>
  <button>button1</button>
  <button>button2</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks really compact. It works in Chrome and Firefox but not Safari. I wonder how about IE10 or IE11?

Comment: I haven't used the prefixed version but Safari 7.1+ supports `flexbox` as do IE10/11- http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: I cannot get this to work in Safari :( .  Apparently `display:-webkit-flex;` is not enough

Comment: Added full prefixed versions

Comment: Can't believe all the extra vendor lines needed! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The reason this is happening is because of the `stretch` element. It is creating a new inline line break. The break is causing another line to appear below the content. If you want to get this completely right, try looking into using [floats](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp) and a [clearfix](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/), but a quick fix is to add this:

`.justified { font-size: 0; }`

Comment: This worked. But in my case `font-size: 0` causes inner buttons font size to be 0 too. I am work-arounding for now. Probably I should check floats and clearfix as you said.

Answer (score 0):

You have a div arround your button while you should modify your button. The following snipplet shows how I would do it.

```css
/* Based on: */
/* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865194/ */
/* http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/EDp8R/ */
div.justified {
    text-align: justify;
    -ms-text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
    text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
    border: thin solid purple;
    
}
div.justified > button {
    border: thin solid green;
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
}
div.justified div.spacer {
    width: 1px;
    display: inline-block;
}
div.justified > span.stretch {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;
}
```

```html
<br/>
<br/>
example 1:
<div class='justified'>
        <button>button1</button>
        <button>button2</button>
    <span class='stretch'></span>
</div>
example 2:
<div class='justified'>
    <div class='spacer'></div>
        <button>button1</button>
    <span class='stretch'></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

add this css -

```
div.justified {
    text-align: justify;
    -ms-text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
    text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
    border: thin solid purple;
    line-height: 0; /* This line */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/usqp2qxf/1/