# How to place two horizontal div's next to a vertical one?

Tags: html, css

I want to align my stuff as:

```
┌────┬─────────────────────────────────┐
│ No │  Some possible long content     │
│    ├─────────────────────────────────┤
│    │  Not so long stuff              │
└────┴─────────────────────────────────┘
```

Using tables would be like 5 minutes using `rowspan=2` but using divs I don't know where to start. I think divs should should be used since this is not tabular data. Is just a way of layout a counter, a possible lone title and its subtitle (not that long):

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="div1">No</div>
    <div class="div2">Some possible long content</div>
    <div class="div3">Not so long stuff</div>
</div>
```

`1` width is constant but its height should be the sum of `2` and `3` height.
`3` always contain one line of code but `2` might contain more than `1` line.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Frankly, it kind of *sounds* like tabular data...and if it works why not? It might not be the latest accepted practice but sometimes you just have to go with what gets the job done.

Comment: you could style your divs like a table with `display:table` etc. Look here: http://www.sitepoint.com/rowspans-colspans-in-css-tables/

Comment: Irrelevant but you can't name a class with only a number!

Comment: Why I am getting voted as closed? I think it is a css question. Not off-topic

Comment: Can we change the HTML at all?

Comment: @VangelTzo Thanks! I just corrected that. Now everyone knows I suck at html/css

Comment: @Paulie_D you mean should I remove the HTML tag?

Comment: No, I mean can we change the HTML structure?

Comment: Yes. That HTML came just from my brain. No particular restrictions as long as it works in all mayor browsers :)

Comment: check my solution it works in all browsers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use css's `display:table` and `display:table-cell`

http://jsfiddle.net/8qv9z762/

```
#container {
    display: table;
    background-color: #dda;
    height: 1px; /*weird but important forgot why*/
}
.r {
    display: table-cell;
}
.div1 {
    height: 100%;
}
.div1, .div2, .div3 {
    border: solid 1px;
    padding: 5px 8px;
}
```

[image]

This has way better support across browser, flexbox is still not supported everywhere.

The table-cell is supported all the way to ie8, whereas, flex is supported only by ie11+ (last two versions)

Only draw back of this technique is you can't have margins. However, that's not a problem as you can have another child container that can be a main wrapper inside table-cell div and it can have margin.

Comment: Paulie_D's answer works in all browsers (by adding the vendor stuff) but this looked a simpler answer :) Thanks!

Comment: yea almost... it wont work in ie8 and ie9 but not sure if they even matter

Comment: This is a nice fallback considering the compatibility, but it's actually almost as ugly as using tables, because you could have just used tables in HTML and left out these bits of CSS instead. Good thing about this, though, is that you can swap the CSS with something more nice, so it's acceptable.

Comment: without flexbox trying to achieve all properties of a table layout using only css but not display table would require javascript's help. Beside it's not ugly as using tables, html structure isn't ruined due to using display: table or so on. It's no more dirty than using display:inline-block

Answer (score 6):

If you can change the HTML structure to wrap the right side divs then `flexbox` can do that.

```css
.container {
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  display: flex;
}
.div1,
.right {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.div1,
.right > div {
  padding: 1em;
}
.div1 {
  background: orange;
}
.div2 {
  background: pink;
}
.div3 {
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="div1">No</div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="div2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet explicabo omnis, suscipit laborum officiis, eius sint ipsam doloremque magnam reiciendis corporis repudiandae ducimus laboriosam ex! Porro dolores aut vitae. Assumenda ut laborum dolor
      fugiat ullam nihil enim sapiente ex vel praesentium quo dolores distinctio, aliquid perferendis non accusamus dolorum excepturi?</div>
    <div class="div3">Not so long stuff</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I added all the vendor stuff for flex as in your other answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/31788693/149008) plus `-ms-flex-direction` and `-webkit-flex-direction` and I worked! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could use absolute positioning, like so: https://jsfiddle.net/sueba6t2/1/

Based on a modified HTML markup (where I renamed some classes to be compliant), here is the css:

```
.container {
    position: relative;
}
.d1 {
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 3em;
}
.d2, .d3 {
    margin-left: 3em;
}
```

Or, if you can change the markup and like newer, fancy stuff, use flex: https://jsfiddle.net/k7e01o29/

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <nav>No</nav>
    <article>
        <section>Long content</section>
        <footer>Not long</footer>
    </article>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
article {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Be aware that the flexible box module is not supported in all browsers. If you want to support IE10 or below, you're going to have to use polyfills, which might be undesirable. Flex is much more powerful than what you are trying to achieve, but it has downsides when it comes to browser support.

Refer to http://caniuse.com/#search=flex for more details.

Comment: Just fyi: `float` should not be used in combination with `position: absolute;`, it is nonsensical. Instead, make it stick to any side of the parent box using `top`, `right`, `bottom` or `left` which you give a value of pixels, `em`s or a percentage.

Comment: You're completely right. I first tried with floats, changed my mind and left the code pending...

Comment: check out my answers, it has solved my life problems ;)