# Vertically align divs with equal space between them

Tags: css

So I'm struggling to achieve this simple concept with CSS and i've also searched the entire internet but couldn't find anything. I think I'm just not wording it correctly so a visual image of what i'm trying to do is this:

[image]

The top box should be positioned on top and the bottom one should be positioned at the bottom. Then the boxes in between them should have equal spacing on top and bottom. This is more like the vertical version of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6880421/7150896

Comment: The container has fixed size? why don't you use margin?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @paolo.basso99 can't use margins because I need the spacing to be calculated dynamically and it should work seamlessly when more boxes are added

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `Flexbox` for this. You just need to set `flex-direction: column` and `justify-content: space-between`.

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.content {
  display: flex;
  height: 250px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 200px;
}
.box {
  background: #0479D9;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome. I have come across flex box but was too lazy to read and understand how it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can also achieve this using grid css layout:

```css
.content {
  display: grid;
  align-content: space-between;
  height: 275px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
}
.box {
  background: #0479D9;
  height: 75px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```