# How to get div to collapse to content horizontally

Tags: html, css, web-applications

I've been trying all day to get a container to display its content in the form of columns and expand towards the side instead of down when the number of children `div`'s increases. I've tried everything from `-vendor-box-orient` layout to `inline-block`, nothing seems to be working. Here is the use case.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="item">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `.container` is supposed to be `overflow-x:scroll` while `.row` is supposed to exceed `.container` if it has enough children to do so, instead of leaving overflow visible. **So, how can I get `.row` to collapse to the width of its collective children as it would work if it was vertical?**

Use case: [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NzXQG/)

Comment: A working demo on http://jsfiddle.net would go a long way to help you. `:)`

Comment: thanks, fixed that little problem.

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/suJ3d/2/ It's works great in Firefox, but I don't want to post it as an answer until I check other browsers. EDIT: And Chrome. EDIT2: IE 8 and 9 yes, 7 no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your fiddle demo, I found [this answer by ThirtyDot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5186832/451969) ([fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/jwJBd/)) and adapted to do the same thing for right-flowing content to be right-fitted. I'm not entirely I got the scroll feature right, but let me know. This should work with elements other than `UL` and `LI` as well, but I haven't modified the markup to check yet.

Of course, this uses the weird and wonderful `display: table-` properties. Doing that, it was bound not to be supported by some legacy browser. See [When Can I Use?](http://caniuse.com/#search=table-) for details on support.

I tested the following:

**Firefox 13** - *Works*
**Chrome Latest** - *Works*
**Opera 11.67** - *Works*
**IE 8** - *Works*
**IE 9** - *Works*
**IE 7** - *Does NOT Work*
**Safari** - *Untested*

So if IE7 support is critical, this won't work for that browser at least. But unless I've misunderstood something, it works great in all the others.

**Markup**

```
<div>
    <div class="super-scroller">
        <ul class="horizontal-fit">
            <li class="outer-block"><span class="inner-block"></span></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.super-scroller {
    border: 1px solid green;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 10px auto;
    width: 90%;
}
.horizontal-fit {
    display: table;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
.horizontal-fit .outer-block {
    display: table-cell;
}
.horizontal-fit .inner-block {
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid red;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 5px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/suJ3d/2/

Interactive demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/suJ3d/5/embedded/result/

Comment: I like how I stupidly forget it only for iPad and you got out of your way to test every browser sans target. Sorry 'bout that...

Comment: Oh. So does it work in the iPad? I don't have one. It works in Chrome! (I can't get Safari to run on my computer, it refuses and pouts in the corner.)

Comment: safari, mob safari and chrome all use webkit so it's no prob. Testing though.

Comment: Good idea using real tables. I guess my brain removed them from cache when it loaded HTML5.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the brain and cache bit meant in that last comment... I put together a [super nifty interactive demo](http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/suJ3d/4/embedded/result/) which also shows the somewhat-interesting thing it does when you apply `margin: auto` to the fitting parent.

Comment: Sorry, literally forgot so much legacy stuff I thought that was a table for a second. List idea superb, thanks. BTW that last comment was a joke.

Comment: TABLE is a savior for so many horizontal layout issues - just be aware that it works horribly with something like jquery slideUp() because when a table's height is set it doesn't crop it - so watch out for that

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example. The red div's move inside the blue div.

The key was

```
overflow-x:scroll;
white-space: nowrap;
```

on the outer div and

```
display:inline-block;
```

on the inner div

http://jsfiddle.net/WTw2P/2/